# Scala best way of turning a Collection into a Map-by-key?

Tags: scala, dictionary, scala-collections

If I have a collection `c` of type `T` and there is a property `p` on `T` (of type `P`, say), what is the best way to do a *map-by-extracting-key*?

```
val c: Collection[T]
val m: Map[P, T]
```

One way is the following:

```
m = new HashMap[P, T]
c foreach { t => m add (t.getP, t) }
```

But now I need a *mutable* map. Is there a better way of doing this so that it's in 1 line and I end up with an *immutable* Map? (Obviously I could turn the above into a simple library utility, as I would in Java, but I suspect that in Scala there is no need)

Answer (score 258, accepted):

You can use

```
c map (t => t.getP -> t) toMap
```

but be aware that this needs 2 traversals.

Comment: I still prefer my suggestions in trac of a `Traversable[K].mapTo( K => V)` and `Traversable[V].mapBy( V => K)` were better!

Comment: As alternative, with zip: `c map (_.getP) zip c toMap`

Comment: Be aware that this is a quadratic operation, but the same goes for most other variants given here. Looking at the source code of scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder etc, it seems to me that for each tuple, a new immutable map is created to which the tuple is added.

Comment: On my machine for a list with 500,000 elements, this Scala code is about 20 times slower than the straight-forward Java approach (create HashMap with appropriate size, loop over list, put elements into map). For 5,000 elements, Scala ist about 8 times slower. The loop approach written in Scala is roughly 3 times faster than the toMap variant, but still between 2 and 7 times slower than Java.

Comment: Would you please provide the test sources to the SO community? Thx.

Comment: Replace `c` with `c.iterator` to avoid creation of intermediate collection.

Comment: @JonaChristopherSahnwaldt Do you have results about performance with Java 8 and lambdas? :)

Comment: @Cherry Good question! In my microbenchmarks, code with or without streams and lamdas has the exact same performance (within measurable precision). Initializing the map with the correct size (including load factor!) makes the process two times faster in each case. The syntax for the initializing the map is a bit awkward with streams. https://gist.github.com/jcsahnwaldt/f904de89a4440a1b0458

Comment: @user573215 Sorry, I can't find the sources anymore.

Comment: The suggestion with breakOut does not work in 2.10 (compiler complains that ```Iterator[(P,T)] does not take parameters```. However, both suggestions work in Scala 2.11.

Answer (score 24):

You can construct a Map with a variable number of tuples.  So use the map method on the collection to convert it into a collection of tuples and then use the : _* trick to convert the result into a variable argument.

```
scala> val list = List("this", "maps", "string", "to", "length") map {s => (s, s.length)}
list: List[(java.lang.String, Int)] = List((this,4), (maps,4), (string,6), (to,2), (length,6))

scala> val list = List("this", "is", "a", "bunch", "of", "strings")
list: List[java.lang.String] = List(this, is, a, bunch, of, strings)

scala> val string2Length = Map(list map {s => (s, s.length)} : _*)
string2Length: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(strings -> 7, of -> 2, bunch -> 5, a -> 1, is -> 2, this -> 4)
```

Comment: I've been reading about Scala for >2 weeks and working through examples and not once had I seen this ": _ *" notation! Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Just for the record, i wonder why we need to precise that this is a sequence with _*. map still convert return a list of tuple here. So why the _* ? I mean it works but i would like to understand the type ascription here

Comment: Is this more efficient than the other methods?

Answer (score 20):

In addition to @James Iry's solution, it is also possible to accomplish this using a fold.  I suspect that this solution is slightly faster than the tuple method (fewer garbage objects are created):

```
val list = List("this", "maps", "string", "to", "length")
val map = list.foldLeft(Map[String, Int]()) { (m, s) => m(s) = s.length }
```

Comment: I will try this out (I'm sure it works :-). What is going on with the "(m,s)=>m(s) = s.length" function? I have seen the typical foldLeft example with a sum and a function "_ + _"; this is much more confusing! The function seems to assume that I already have a tuple (m,s), which I don't really get

Comment: *Is* this right? According to the scaladoc of foldLeft:
    "foldLeft  [B](z : B)(op : (B, A) => B) : B"
B in this case must be a Map[String, Int], so I don't really understand the function in your example at all! It should return a Map for a start, shouldn't it?

Comment: OK - so I've got this! "m(s) = s.length" (where m is a map) returns a new map with the mapping "s -> s.length". How was I supposed to know this? I can't find it anywhere in the programming in scala sections on maps!

Comment: That is scala's syntactic sugar for update: An assignment f(args) = e with a function application to the left of the '=' operator is interpreted as f.update(args, e), i.e. the invocation of an update function defined by f. [The Scala Language Specification Version 2.7, 6.15 Assignments]

Comment: Man, Scala was weird back then!

Comment: @Daniel I try your code, but appear following error: "value update is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]". Please explain your code how to working this code?

Comment: doesnt seem to work.for me either "Application does not take parameters"

Comment: @jayunit100 This is because fold left has to return a value after each iteration as well. This should work. `list.foldLeft(Map[String, Int]()) { (m, s) => m(s) = s.length; m }` Also sorry for being 10 months too late :-)

Comment: Immutable version: `list.foldLeft(Map[String,Int]()) { (m,s) => m + (s -> s.length) }`. Note that if you want to use comma to build the tuple, you need an extra pair of parentheses: `((s, s.length))`.

Answer (score 14):

This can be implemented immutably and with a single traversal by folding through the collection as follows.

```
val map = c.foldLeft(Map[P, T]()) { (m, t) => m + (t.getP -> t) }
```

The solution works because adding to an immutable Map returns a new immutable Map with the additional entry and this value serves as the accumulator through the fold operation.

The tradeoff here is the simplicity of the code versus its efficiency. So, for large collections, this approach may be more suitable than using 2 traversal implementations such as applying `map` and `toMap`.

Answer (score 9):

Another solution (might not work for all types)

```
import scala.collection.breakOut
val m:Map[P, T] = c.map(t => (t.getP, t))(breakOut)
```

this avoids the creation of the intermediary list, more info here:
[Scala 2.8 breakOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout)

Answer (score 8):

What you're trying to achieve is a bit undefined.
What if two or more items in `c` share the same `p`? Which item will be mapped to that `p` in the map?

The more accurate way of looking at this is yielding a map between `p` and all `c` items that have it:

```
val m: Map[P, Collection[T]]
```

This could be easily achieved with [groupBy](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.GenTraversableLike@groupBy[K](f:A=%3EK):scala.collection.GenMap[K,Repr]):

```
val m: Map[P, Collection[T]] = c.groupBy(t => t.p)
```

If you still want the original map, you can, for instance, map `p` to the first `t` that has it:

```
val m: Map[P, T] = c.groupBy(t => t.p) map { case (p, ts) =>  p -> ts.head }
```

Comment: One handy tweak on this is to use ```collect``` instead of ```map```. Eg: ```c.group(t => t.p) collect { case (Some(p), ts) => p -> ts.head }```. This way you can do things like flatten maps when you key is an Option[_].

Comment: @healsjnr Sure, this could be said for any map. It isn't the core issue here, though.

Comment: You could use `.mapValues(_.head)` instead of the map.

Answer (score 6):

Scala 2.13+

instead of "breakOut" you could use

`c.map(t => (t.getP, t)).to(Map)`

Scroll to "View": https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2017/02/28/collections-rework.html

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the most efficient way to turn a list to map, but it makes the calling code more readable. I used implicit conversions to add a **mapBy** method to List:

```
implicit def list2ListWithMapBy[T](list: List[T]): ListWithMapBy[T] = {
  new ListWithMapBy(list)
}

class ListWithMapBy[V](list: List[V]){
  def mapBy[K](keyFunc: V => K) = {
    list.map(a => keyFunc(a) -> a).toMap
  }
}
```

Calling code example:

```
val list = List("A", "AA", "AAA")
list.mapBy(_.length)                  //Map(1 -> A, 2 -> AA, 3 -> AAA)
```

Note that because of the implicit conversion, the caller code needs to import scala's implicitConversions.

Answer (score 2):

```
c map (_.getP) zip c
```

Works well and is very intuitiv

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: I'm sorry. But, this IS an answer to the question "Scala best way of turning a Collection into a Map-by-key?" as Ben Lings is.

Comment: And Ben didn't provide any explanation?

Comment: this creates two lists and combine into a "map" using the elements in `c` as key (sort of). Note "map" because the resulting collection is not a scala `Map` but creates another list/iterable of tuples...but the effect is the same for the OP's purpose i wouldn't discount the simplicity but it's not as efficient as `foldLeft` solution, nor it's the real answer to the question "converting into a collection into a map-by-key"

Answer (score 2):

How about using zip and toMap?

```
myList.zip(myList.map(_.length)).toMap
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here are two *pointless* ways of doing it:

```
scala> case class Foo(bar: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> val c = Vector(Foo(9), Foo(11))
c: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Foo] = Vector(Foo(9), Foo(11))

scala> c.map(((_: Foo).bar) &&& identity).toMap
res30: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Foo] = Map(9 -> Foo(9), 11 -> Foo(11))

scala> c.map(((_: Foo).bar) >>= (Pair.apply[Int, Foo] _).curried).toMap
res31: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Foo] = Map(9 -> Foo(9), 11 -> Foo(11))
```

Comment: Also, fwiw, this is how those two would look in Haskell: `Map.fromList $ map (bar &&& id) c`, `Map.fromList $ map (bar >>= (,)) c`.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

```
val personsMap = persons.foldLeft(scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, PersonDTO]()) {
    (m, p) => m(p.id) = p; m
}
```

The Map has to be mutable and the Map has to be return since adding to a mutable Map does not return a map.

Comment: Actually, it can be implemented immutably as follows:
  
```val personsMap = persons.foldLeft(Map[Int, PersonDTO]()) {
        (m, p) => m + (p.id -> p)
    }```
The Map can be immutable, as evidenced above, because adding to an immutable Map returns a new immutable Map with the additional entry. This value serves as the accumulator through the fold operation.

Answer (score -3):

use map() on collection followed with toMap

```
val map = list.map(e => (e, e.length)).toMap
```

Comment: How is this different from the answer that was submitted, and accepted, 7 years ago?