# Scala 2.8 breakOut

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

In Scala **2.8**, there is an object in `scala.collection.package.scala`:

```
def breakOut[From, T, To](implicit b : CanBuildFrom[Nothing, T, To]) =
    new CanBuildFrom[From, T, To] {
        def apply(from: From) = b.apply() ; def apply() = b.apply()
 }
```

I have been told that this results in:

```
> import scala.collection.breakOut
> val map : Map[Int,String] = List("London", "Paris").map(x => (x.length, x))(breakOut)

map: Map[Int,String] = Map(6 -> London, 5 -> Paris)
```

What is going on here? Why is `breakOut` being called *as an argument* to my `List`?

Comment: The trivial answer being, it is not an argument to `List`, but to `map`.

Comment: Strting from v.2.13 collection.breakOut no longer exists, use .view and .to(Collection) instead. https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/collections-migration-213.html

Answer (score 338, accepted):

The answer is found on the definition of `map`:

```
def map[B, That](f : (A) => B)(implicit bf : CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]) : That
```

Note that it has two parameters. The first is your function and the second is an implicit. If you do not provide that implicit, Scala will choose the most *specific* one available.

**About `breakOut`**

So, what's the purpose of `breakOut`? Consider the example given for the question, You take a list of strings, transform each string into a tuple `(Int, String)`, and then produce a `Map` out of it. The most obvious way to do that would produce an intermediary `List[(Int, String)]` collection, and then convert it.

Given that `map` uses a `Builder` to produce the resulting collection, wouldn't it be possible to skip the intermediary `List` and collect the results directly into a `Map`? Evidently, yes, it is. To do so, however, we need to pass a proper `CanBuildFrom` to `map`, and that is exactly what `breakOut` does.

Let's look, then, at the definition of `breakOut`:

```
def breakOut[From, T, To](implicit b : CanBuildFrom[Nothing, T, To]) =
  new CanBuildFrom[From, T, To] {
    def apply(from: From) = b.apply() ; def apply() = b.apply()
  }
```

Note that `breakOut` is parameterized, and that it returns an instance of `CanBuildFrom`. As it happens, the types `From`, `T` and `To` have already been inferred, because we know that `map` is expecting `CanBuildFrom[List[String], (Int, String), Map[Int, String]]`. Therefore:

```
From = List[String]
T = (Int, String)
To = Map[Int, String]
```

To conclude let's examine the implicit received by `breakOut` itself. It is of type `CanBuildFrom[Nothing,T,To]`. We already know all these types, so we can determine that we need an implicit of type `CanBuildFrom[Nothing,(Int,String),Map[Int,String]]`. But is there such a definition?

Let's look at `CanBuildFrom`'s definition:

```
trait CanBuildFrom[-From, -Elem, +To] 
extends AnyRef
```

So `CanBuildFrom` is contra-variant on its first type parameter. Because `Nothing` is a bottom class (ie, it is a subclass of everything), that means *any* class can be used in place of `Nothing`.

Since such a builder exists, Scala can use it to produce the desired output.

**About Builders**

A lot of methods from Scala's collections library consists of taking the original collection, processing it somehow (in the case of `map`, transforming each element), and storing the results in a new collection.

To maximize code reuse, this storing of results is done through a *builder* (`scala.collection.mutable.Builder`), which basically supports two operations: appending elements, and returning the resulting collection. The type of this resulting collection will depend on the type of the builder. Thus, a `List` builder will return a `List`, a `Map` builder will return a `Map`, and so on. The implementation of the `map` method need not concern itself with the type of the result: the builder takes care of it.

On the other hand, that means that `map` needs to receive this builder somehow. The problem faced when designing Scala 2.8 Collections was how to choose the best builder possible. For example, if I were to write `Map('a' -> 1).map(_.swap)`, I'd like to get a `Map(1 -> 'a')` back. On the other hand, a `Map('a' -> 1).map(_._1)` can't return a `Map` (it returns an `Iterable`).

The magic of producing the best possible `Builder` from the known types of the expression is performed through this `CanBuildFrom` implicit.

**About `CanBuildFrom`**

To better explain what's going on, I'll give an example where the collection being mapped is a `Map` instead of a `List`. I'll go back to `List` later. For now, consider these two expressions:

```
Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two") map Function.tupled(_ -> _.length)
Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two") map (_._2)
```

The first returns a `Map` and the second returns an `Iterable`. The magic of returning a fitting collection is the work of `CanBuildFrom`. Let's consider the definition of `map` again to understand it.

The method `map` is inherited from `TraversableLike`. It is parameterized on `B` and `That`, and makes use of the type parameters `A` and `Repr`, which parameterize the class. Let's see both definitions together:

The class `TraversableLike` is defined as:

```
trait TraversableLike[+A, +Repr] 
extends HasNewBuilder[A, Repr] with AnyRef

def map[B, That](f : (A) => B)(implicit bf : CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]) : That
```

To understand where `A` and `Repr` come from, let's consider the definition of `Map` itself:

```
trait Map[A, +B] 
extends Iterable[(A, B)] with Map[A, B] with MapLike[A, B, Map[A, B]]
```

Because `TraversableLike` is inherited by all traits which extend `Map`, `A` and `Repr` could be inherited from any of them. The last one gets the preference, though. So, following the definition of the immutable `Map` and all the traits that connect it to `TraversableLike`, we have:

```
trait Map[A, +B] 
extends Iterable[(A, B)] with Map[A, B] with MapLike[A, B, Map[A, B]]

trait MapLike[A, +B, +This <: MapLike[A, B, This] with Map[A, B]] 
extends MapLike[A, B, This]

trait MapLike[A, +B, +This <: MapLike[A, B, This] with Map[A, B]] 
extends PartialFunction[A, B] with IterableLike[(A, B), This] with Subtractable[A, This]

trait IterableLike[+A, +Repr] 
extends Equals with TraversableLike[A, Repr]

trait TraversableLike[+A, +Repr] 
extends HasNewBuilder[A, Repr] with AnyRef
```

If you pass the type parameters of `Map[Int, String]` all the way down the chain, we find that the types passed to `TraversableLike`, and, thus, used by `map`, are:

```
A = (Int,String)
Repr = Map[Int, String]
```

Going back to the example, the first map is receiving a function of type `((Int, String)) => (Int, Int)` and the second map is receiving a function of type `((Int, String)) => String`. I use the double parenthesis to emphasize it is a tuple being received, as that's the type of `A` as we saw.

With that information, let's consider the other types.

```
map Function.tupled(_ -> _.length):
B = (Int, Int)

map (_._2):
B = String
```

We can see that the type returned by the first `map` is `Map[Int,Int]`, and the second is `Iterable[String]`. Looking at `map`'s definition, it is easy to see that these are the values of `That`. But where do they come from?

If we look inside the companion objects of the classes involved, we see some implicit declarations providing them. On object `Map`:

```
implicit def  canBuildFrom [A, B] : CanBuildFrom[Map, (A, B), Map[A, B]]
```

And on object `Iterable`, whose class is extended by `Map`:

```
implicit def  canBuildFrom [A] : CanBuildFrom[Iterable, A, Iterable[A]]
```

These definitions provide factories for parameterized `CanBuildFrom`.

Scala will choose the most specific implicit available. In the first case, it was the first `CanBuildFrom`. In the second case, as the first did not match, it chose the second `CanBuildFrom`.

**Back to the Question**

Let's see the code for the question, `List`'s and `map`'s definition (again) to see how the types are inferred:

```
val map : Map[Int,String] = List("London", "Paris").map(x => (x.length, x))(breakOut)

sealed abstract class List[+A] 
extends LinearSeq[A] with Product with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, List] with LinearSeqLike[A, List[A]]

trait LinearSeqLike[+A, +Repr <: LinearSeqLike[A, Repr]] 
extends SeqLike[A, Repr]

trait SeqLike[+A, +Repr] 
extends IterableLike[A, Repr]

trait IterableLike[+A, +Repr] 
extends Equals with TraversableLike[A, Repr]

trait TraversableLike[+A, +Repr] 
extends HasNewBuilder[A, Repr] with AnyRef

def map[B, That](f : (A) => B)(implicit bf : CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]) : That
```

The type of `List("London", "Paris")` is `List[String]`, so the types `A` and `Repr` defined on `TraversableLike` are:

```
A = String
Repr = List[String]
```

The type for `(x => (x.length, x))` is `(String) => (Int, String)`, so the type of `B` is:

```
B = (Int, String)
```

The last unknown type, `That` is the type of the result of `map`, and we already have that as well:

```
val map : Map[Int,String] =
```

So,

```
That = Map[Int, String]
```

That means `breakOut` must, necessarily, return a type or subtype of `CanBuildFrom[List[String], (Int, String), Map[Int, String]]`.

Comment: Daniel - in my example, I started off with a `Traversable` and wanted to turn it into a Map. I appreciate the time you've taken over this answer - really - but do you mind altering it? I'm struggling to understand what is going on because it doesn't precisely answer the question I asked

Comment: Chris, I address the question when I get back to `breakOut`. I think it is important to begin with the example on `Map`, because it makes clear what the purpose of `CanBuildFrom` is. I'll try to make clear the transition back to your question.

Comment: Ok, I have finished revising the answer. I noticed some code I had once written had been removed from the final answer, so it is no suprise you found it difficult to follow. But I caution that it *is* difficult to understand. If I didn't know the answer, I'd never be able to explain it! :-)

Comment: Daniel, I can grovel through the types in your answer, but once I get to the end, I feel like I haven't gained any high level understanding. What *is* breakOut? Where does the name "breakOut" come from (what am I breaking out of)? Why is it needed in this case in order to get a Map out? Surely is there is *some* way to briefly answer these questions? (even if the lengthy type-groveling remains necessary in order to grasp every detail)

Comment: @Seth That's a valid concern, but I'm not sure I'm up to the task. The origin of this can be found in here: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.internals/1812/match=support+explicit+builders. I'll think about it, but, right now, I can't think of much of a way to improve it.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid specifying the entire result type of Map[Int, String]  and instead being able to write something like: 'val map = List("London", "Paris").map(x => (x.length, x))(breakOut[...Map])'

Comment: It's possible to write `List(1, 2, 3).as[Vector]` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074118/scala-how-do-i-convert-a-mapint-any-to-a-sortedmap-or-a-treemap/3075515#3075515

Comment: @retronym is that a question or a statement?

Comment: @IttayD See retronym's answer to your question, above.

Comment: yep, i already upvoted him. to fully get what I wanted:

  class TraversableT[A,B](t: Traversable[(A,B)]) {
    def as[CC[X,Y] <: Traversable[(X,Y)]](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, (A, B), CC[A, B]]): CC[A, B] = t.map(identity)(collection.breakOut)
  }

  implicit def ToTraverseableT[A, B](t: Traversable[(A, B)]): TraversableT[A, B] = new TraversableT[A, B](t)

Comment: @SethTisue From my reading of this explanation, it seems that breakOut is necessary to "break out" of the requirement that your builder needs to build from a List[String]. The compiler wants a CanBuildFrom[List[String], (Int,String), Map[Int,String]], which you cannot provide. The breakOut function does this by clobbering the first type parameter in CanBuildFrom by setting it to Nothing. Now you only have to provide a CanBuildFrom[Nothing, (Int,String), Map[Int,String]]. This is easy because it's provided by the Map class.

Comment: @Mark When I found breakOut, the problem that I saw it addressing was the way that monads insist on mapping (via bind/flatMap) to their own type.  It allows one to "break out" of a mapping chain using one monad into a different monad type.  I have no idea whether that's what how Adriaan Moors (the author) was thinking about it, though!

Comment: Reading [Architecture of Scala Collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html) helped me understanding this answer.

Answer (score 86):

I'd like to build upon Daniel's answer. It was very thorough, but as noted in the comments, it doesn't explain what breakout does.

Taken from *[Re: Support for explicit Builders](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.internals/1812/match=support+explicit+builders)* (2009-10-23), here is what I believe breakout does:

It gives the compiler a suggestion as to which Builder to choose implicitly (essentially it allows the compiler to choose which factory it thinks fits the situation best.)

For example, see the following:

```
scala> import scala.collection.generic._
import scala.collection.generic._

scala> import scala.collection._
import scala.collection._

scala> import scala.collection.mutable._
import scala.collection.mutable._

scala>

scala> def breakOut[From, T, To](implicit b : CanBuildFrom[Nothing, T, To]) =
     |    new CanBuildFrom[From, T, To] {
     |       def apply(from: From) = b.apply() ; def apply() = b.apply()
     |    }
breakOut: [From, T, To]
     |    (implicit b: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,T,To])
     |    java.lang.Object with
     |    scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[From,T,To]

scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val imp = l.map(_ + 1)(breakOut)
imp: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 3, 4)

scala> val arr: Array[Int] = l.map(_ + 1)(breakOut)
imp: Array[Int] = Array(2, 3, 4)

scala> val stream: Stream[Int] = l.map(_ + 1)(breakOut)
stream: Stream[Int] = Stream(2, ?)

scala> val seq: Seq[Int] = l.map(_ + 1)(breakOut)
seq: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(2, 3, 4)

scala> val set: Set[Int] = l.map(_ + 1)(breakOut)
seq: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(2, 4, 3)

scala> val hashSet: HashSet[Int] = l.map(_ + 1)(breakOut)
seq: scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[Int] = Set(2, 4, 3)
```

You can see the return type is implicitly chosen by the compiler to best match the expected type.  Depending on how you declare the receiving variable, you get different results.

The following would be an equivalent way to specify a builder.  Note in this case, the compiler will infer the expected type based on the builder's type:

```
scala> def buildWith[From, T, To](b : Builder[T, To]) =
     |    new CanBuildFrom[From, T, To] {
     |      def apply(from: From) = b ; def apply() = b
     |    }
buildWith: [From, T, To]
     |    (b: scala.collection.mutable.Builder[T,To])
     |    java.lang.Object with
     |    scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[From,T,To]

scala> val a = l.map(_ + 1)(buildWith(Array.newBuilder[Int]))
a: Array[Int] = Array(2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: I wonder why it's named "`breakOut`"? I'm thinking something like `convert` or `buildADifferentTypeOfCollection` (but shorter) might have been easier to remember.

Answer (score 12):

Daniel Sobral's answer is great, and should be read together with [Architecture of Scala Collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html) (Chapter 25 of Programming in Scala).

I just wanted to elaborate on why it is called `breakOut`:

## Why is it called `breakOut`?

Because we want to ***break out of one type and into another***:

Break out of what type into what type? Lets look at the `map` function on `Seq` as an example:

```
Seq.map[B, That](f: (A) -> B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Seq[A], B, That]): That
```

If we wanted to build a Map directly from mapping over the elements of a sequence such as:

```
val x: Map[String, Int] = Seq("A", "BB", "CCC").map(s => (s, s.length))
```

The compiler would complain:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Seq[(String, Int)]
required: Map[String,Int]
```

The reason being that Seq only knows how to build another Seq (i.e. there is an implicit `CanBuildFrom[Seq[_], B, Seq[B]]` builder factory available, but there is **NO** builder factory from Seq to Map).

In order to compile, we need to somehow ***`breakOut` of the type requirement***, and be able to construct a builder that produces a Map for the `map` function to use.

As Daniel has explained, breakOut has the following signature:

```
def breakOut[From, T, To](implicit b: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, T, To]): CanBuildFrom[From, T, To] =
    // can't just return b because the argument to apply could be cast to From in b
    new CanBuildFrom[From, T, To] {
      def apply(from: From) = b.apply()
      def apply()           = b.apply()
    }
```

`Nothing` is a subclass of all classes, so any builder factory can be substituted in place of `implicit b: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, T, To]`. If we used the breakOut function to provide the implicit parameter:

```
val x: Map[String, Int] = Seq("A", "BB", "CCC").map(s => (s, s.length))(collection.breakOut)
```

It would compile, because `breakOut` is able to provide the required type of `CanBuildFrom[Seq[(String, Int)], (String, Int), Map[String, Int]]`, while the compiler is able to find an implicit builder factory of type `CanBuildFrom[Map[_, _], (A, B), Map[A, B]]`, in place of `CanBuildFrom[Nothing, T, To]`, for breakOut to use to create the actual builder.

Note that `CanBuildFrom[Map[_, _], (A, B), Map[A, B]]` is defined in Map, and simply initiates a `MapBuilder` which uses an underlying Map.

Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 7):

A simple example to understand what `breakOut` does:

```
scala> import collection.breakOut
import collection.breakOut

scala> val set = Set(1, 2, 3, 4)
set: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> set.map(_ % 2)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 0)

scala> val seq:Seq[Int] = set.map(_ % 2)(breakOut)
seq: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 0, 1, 0) // map created a Seq[Int] instead of the default Set[Int]
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! Also `val seq:Seq[Int] = set.map(_ % 2).toVector` will not give you the repeated values as the `Set` was preserved for the `map`.

Comment: @MatthewPickering correct! `set.map(_ % 2)` creates a `Set(1, 0)` first, which then gets converted to a `Vector(1, 0)`.