# Scala 2.8 CanBuildFrom

Tags: generics, scala, scala-2.8

Following on from another question I asked, *[Scala 2.8 breakout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout)*, I wanted to understand a bit more about the Scala method `TraversableLike[A].map` whose signature is as follows:

```
def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That
```

Notice a few things about this method:

- It takes a function turning each `A` in the traversable into a `B`.
- It returns `That` and takes an implicit argument of type `CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]`.

I can call this as follows:

```
> val s: Set[Int] = List("Paris", "London").map(_.length)
s: Set[Int] Set(5,6)
```

What **I cannot quite grasp** is how the fact that `That` is *bound* to `B` (that is, it is some collection of B's) is being enforced by the compiler. The type parameters look to be independent of both the signature above and of the signature of the trait `CanBuildFrom` itself:

```
trait CanBuildFrom[-From, -Elem, +To]
```

How is the Scala compiler ensuring that `That` cannot be *forced* into something which does not make sense?

```
> val s: Set[String] = List("Paris", "London").map(_.length) //will not compile
```

How does the compiler decide what implicit `CanBuildFrom` objects are in scope for the call?

Comment: Here is the post with a quite nice explanation http://blog.bruchez.name/2012/08/getting-to-know-canbuildfrom-without-phd.html

Comment: For the record, such usage has a conceptual name: return type polymorphism.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Note that the second argument to `map` is an implicit argument. There **must** be an implicit in scope with the appropriate types, or, otherwise, you **must** pass such an argument.

In your example, `That` must be `Set[String]`, B must be `Int` and `Repr` must be `List[String]`. Therefore, for that to compile you need the following implicit object in scope:

```
implicit object X: CanBuildFrom[List[String], Int, Set[String]]
```

There's no such thing in scope. Also, `breakOut` can't provide it, because it, itself, needs an implicit `CanBuildFrom`, whose first type can be any class (a contra-variant descendant of `Nothing`), but otherwise restricted by the other types.

Take a look, for instance, on the `CanBuildFrom` factory from the companion object of `List`:

```
implicit def  canBuildFrom [A] : CanBuildFrom[List, A, List[A]]
```

Because it binds the second and third parameters through `A`, the implicit in question won't work.

So, how does one know where to look for, regarding such implicits? First of all, Scala does import a few things into all scopes. Right now, I can recall the following imports:

```
import scala.package._ // Package object
import scala.Predef._  // Object
// import scala.LowPriorityImplicits, class inherited by Predef
import scala.runtime._ // Package
```

Since we are concerned about implicits, note that when you import things from packages, the only implicits possible are singletons. When you import things from objects (singletons), on the other hand, you can have implicit definitions, values and singletons.

Right now, there are `CanBuildFrom` implicits inside `Predef` and `LowPriorityImplicits`, which are concerned with strings. They enable us to write `"this is a string" map (_.toInt)`.

So, barring these automatic imports, and the explicit imports you make, where else can an implicit be found? One place: the companion objects of the instance on which the method is being applied.

I say companion object*s*, in the plural, because the companion objects of all traits and classes inherited by the class of the instance in question may contain relevant implicits. I'm not sure if the instance itself may contain an implicit. To be honest, I can't reproduce this right now, so I'm certainly making a mistake of some kind here.

At any rate, look inside the companion objects.

Comment: Daniel - how do I know what `implicit` objects are in scope at a given point in my code? That's what the question boils down to, I realize. Where is it specified? Also, this question has nothing to do with `breakOut`.

Comment: Apart from the implicit conversions in object scala.Predef, you have to either define the implicit in the same or an enclosing scope or you have to explicitly import that implicit.

Comment: "when you import things from packages, the only implicits possible are singletons" Is it still true with the Scala 2.8 package objects? They could contain implicit defs and vals, too.

Comment: @JPP package objects are neither package nor objects -- they are package objects. The objects rule apply for them.

Comment: What I meant is that if you wrote `import scala._`, you'd import all classes and traits defined in package `scala`, plus everything in the `scala` package object, which may contain implicit vals and defs (or am I mistaken?). But of course, the scala package is preimported, this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
object ArrayBuffer extends SeqFactory[ArrayBuffer] {
  /** $genericCanBuildFromInfo */
  implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, ArrayBuffer[A]] = new GenericCanBuildFrom[A]
  def newBuilder[A]: Builder[A, ArrayBuffer[A]] = new ArrayBuffer[A]
}
```