# Generic way to refer to "list" in Scala?

Tags: scala

How can I refer to ArrayBuffer and Vector in a more generic way?

For example - one of my functions takes a Vector as an argument, while another returns an ArrayBuffer.
What is a common "iterface" that I can use?

For example, in Java I could use **List** or **Collection** interface to pass them around.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722137/scala-2-8-collections-design-tutorial/1724807.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [here](http://www.decodified.com/scala/collections-api.xml) for an overview of the inheritance relationship between the collections classes.

You'll see that [IndexedSeq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IndexedSeq.html) is a common trait for both ArrayBuffer and Vector.

EDIT: IndexedSeq vs. Seq:

From the doc: `Indexed sequences do not add any new methods wrt Seq, but promise efficient implementations of random access patterns.` This means that, in this context, you could just as well use Seq, as the implementations will be provided by ArrayBuffer and Vector in any case.

Comment: Why not just "Seq"? I mean how do you decide? In java i only had a limited number of choices...

Comment: Ah, the curse of unlimited choices...from the doc: `Indexed sequences do not add any new methods wrt Seq, but promise efficient implementations of random access patterns.` This means that, in this context, you could just as well use Seq, as the implementations will be provided by ArrayBuffer and Vector in any case.

Comment: Could you amend your answer with this comment so that I can accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would use [SeqLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SeqLike.html) or more generic [TraversableOnce](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.html) which would also apply for `Map`s.

Comment: Why not just use Traversable or Seq?

Comment: You're right, that would be sufficient for Vector and ArrayBuffer (+1)

Comment: `SeqLike` isn't much use in this case, as you still have the supply the actual representation as a type param.  `Seq` is the idiomatic choice here, it's less restrictive than `Traversable` and has implementations of some methods that perform better than Traversable's