# How do I deal with Scala collections generically?

Tags: scala, collections

I have realized that my typical way of passing Scala collections around could use some improvement.

```
def doSomethingCool(theFoos: List[Foo]) = { /* insert cool stuff here */ }

// if I happen to have a List
doSomethingCool(theFoos)

// but elsewhere I may have a Vector, Set, Option, ...
doSomethingCool(theFoos.toList)
```

I tend to write my library functions to take a `List` as the parameter type, but I'm certain that there's something more general I can put there to avoid all the occasional `.toList` calls I have in the application code.  This is especially annoying since my `doSomethingCool` function typically only needs to call `map`, `flatMap` and `filter`, which are defined on all the collection types.

What are my options for that 'something more general'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are more general traits, each of which extends the previous one:

- `GenTraversableOnce`
- `GenTraversable`
- `GenIterable`
- `GenSeq`

The traits above do not specify whether the collection is sequential or parallel. If your code requires that things be executed sequentially (typically, if your code has side effects of any kind), they are too general for it.

The following traits mandate sequential execution:

- `TraversableOnce`
- `Traversable`
- `Iterable`
- `Seq`
- `LinearSeq`

The first one, `TraversableOnce` only allows you to call one method on the collection. After that, the collection has been "used". In exchange, it is general enough to accept iterators as well as collections.

`Traversable` is a pretty general collection that has most methods. There are some things it cannot do, however, in which case you need to go to `Iterable`.

All `Iterable` implement the `iterator` method, which allows you to get an `Iterator` for that collection. This gives it the capability for a few methods not present in `Traversable`.

A `Seq[A]` implements the function `Int => A`, which means you can access any element by its index. This is not guaranteed to be efficient, but it is a guarantee that each element *has* an index, and that you can make assertions about what that index is going to be. Contrast this with `Map` and `Set`, where you cannot tell what the index of an element is.

A `LinearSeq` is a `Seq` that provides fast `head`, `tail`, `isEmpty` and prepend. This is as close as you can get to a `List` without actually using a `List` explicitly.

Alternatively, you could have an `IndexedSeq`, which has fast indexed access (something `List` does not provide).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1722137/53013) and [this FAQ](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/collections.html) based on it.

Comment: Very complete response.  The the question and FAQ are very helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you say a few words about how `TraversableLike` etc fit in?

Comment: @LuigiPlinge `TraversableLike` & cia are intended for extenders of collections, not consumers. I'd rather not muddle the issue here.

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious one is to use `Traversable` as the most *general* trait which will have the goodies you want. However, I think you are generally better sticking to:

- `Seq`
- `IndexedSeq`
- `Set`
- `Map`

A `Seq` will cover `List`, `Vector` etc, `IndexedSeq` will cover `Vector` etc etc. I found myself not using `Iterable` because I often need (or want) to know the size of the thing I have and back [*pre scala-2.8* `Iterable` did not provide access to this](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.7/scala/Iterable.html), so I kept having to turn things into sequences anyway!

Looks like `Traversable` and `Iterable` now have `size` methods so maybe I should go back to using them! Of course you could start "going mad" with `GenTraversableOnce` but that is not likely to aid in readability.

Comment: Thanks! `Seq` does not cover `Option` or Lift's [`Box`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.3/net/liftweb/common/Box.html), which is usually what I have. I'll try out `Traversable` and `Iterable`.

Comment: Take care when using `Iterable`. If you get a `Set` and call `map` on it, equal elements of the map-result will get "merged". This might not be what you want to do.

Comment: Traversable and Iterable have always had size (well, since 2.8.0).

Comment: Yes - but I didn't notice that `Traversable` had size; I got used to calling `toList` to get size