# Scala Collections Library Inheritance

Tags: scala

I'm trying to work out how all the traits like `Seq`, `Iterable`, `Traverable`, `TraversableLike` all work together.

I'm slowly getting a bit of a spider web diagram, as I try and draw the relationships in a UML class diagram.

Is there a reason that for example `scala.collection.immutable.Seq` inherits from `scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate`, even though it inherits that trait from its parent `scala.collection.immutable.Iterable`?

The collections API seems to be full of duplicated inheritances, which is leading me to think I haven't understood something...

Cheers,
Ant

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722137/scala-2-8-collections-design-tutorial/1724807#1724807 for a start.

Comment: [This page](http://www.decodified.com/scala/collections-api.xml) has a copy of the diagrams in the answer listed above.  I like it better because it's searchable and has links to the appropriate scaladoc pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`trait Seq [+A] extends Iterable[A] with Seq[A] with GenericTraversableTemplate[A,`**Seq**`] with SeqLike[A, Seq[A]] with Parallelizable[A, ParSeq[A]]`

`trait Iterable [+A] extends Traversable[A] with Iterable[A] with GenericTraversableTemplate[A,`**Iterable**`] with IterableLike[A, Iterable[A]] with Parallelizable[A, ParIterable[A]]`

As you can see, `Seq` and `Traversable` actually extend `GenericTraversableTemplate` with different type parameters, so that, for example, method `flatten` has appropriate return type in each case.