# Scala's MapLike, ListLike, SeqLike, etc how does each compare to Map, List, Seq?

Tags: scala, collections, traits

Could someone please help me understand Scala's various "Like" traits in the collection API. I've been reading over and trying to compare each without luck. I think I can see that Map for example, extends MapLike - adding 2 concrete methods. But this begs the question of why do this at all? Why not just have 1 Map trait in the Collections API instead of Map and MapLike?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala 2.8 collections design tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722137/scala-2-8-collections-design-tutorial)

Comment: Not actually a duplicate... this question is subsumed by that one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best source for these details is [Martin Odersky and Lex Spoon's "What's New in Scala 2.8: The Architecture of Scala Collections"](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/scala_collections_architecture.html):

> The Scala collection library avoids code duplication and achieves the
>   "same-result-type" principle by using generic builders and traversals
>   over collections in so-called *implementation traits*. These traits
>   are named with a `Like` suffix; for instance, `IndexedSeqLike` is the
>   implementation trait for `IndexedSeq`, and similarly,
>   `TraversableLike` is the implementation trait for `Traversable`.
>   Collection classes such as `Traversable` or `IndexedSeq` inherit all
>   their concrete method implementations from these traits.
>   Implementation traits have two type parameters instead of one for
>   normal collections. They parameterize not only over the collection's
>   element type, but also over the collection's *representation type*,
>   *i.e.*, the type of the underlying collection, such as `Seq[I]` or `List[T]`...

The whole article is extremely useful if you want to integrate your own collection classes with the Collections API, or if you just want a deeper understanding of how the library works.

Comment: I have to say, from just reading this excerpt, I am not much wiser (I have the same question as @LalolnDublin ) :( I see that there are implementation of some more general traits, but I can't really seem where that would be useful.

Comment: @Karel: Try the article! It's worth the effort. A full explanation would be too long to copy here, and I didn't see any point in paraphrasing when the original source is so easily available and already very clear.

Comment: Thank you, after reading the article a couple of times I am still having trouble grasping the concept (being new to scala doesn't help) but one key item seems to be the concept that "TraversableLike" (with 2 type params) allows someone to use the Traverable interface without being restricted to a uniform type representation of both element and representation of the data. I don't fully understand this without more examples, but I feel like I'm a step closer!