# Seq, SeqLike, GenSeq or GenSeqLike?

Tags: scala, types, interface, idioms

When a create a function, should I have it take as an argument `Seq`, `SeqLike`, `GenSeq`, or `GenSeqLike`? (So many choices!)

My only requirements is that I can `map` over it and produce a collection with the same number and order of arguments as before.

Typically I "program to interfaces" and choose the most general type possible. In this case, that would be a `GenSeqLike`.

Is this correct/idiomatic?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11443493

Answer (score 3):

`SeqLike` is just an implementation layer for `Seq` that allows you to specify return types.  There are extremely few things that are `SeqLike` but not `Seq`, and those are arguably an error.  So you can feel comfortable not worrying about the `-Like`s.  (If you want to build new collections of the type you are given and keep the types straight, use `CanBuildFrom` instead.)

So then the question is whether to use `GenSeq` or `Seq`.  The problem with `GenSeq` is that the processing might be done in parallel, which means you have to *avoid* using any operation where that could violate your expectations (e.g. summing with a `foreach`).  Furthermore, the general consensus seems to be that the `GenX` part of the collections hierarchy overcomplicates the collections and makes it more difficult to incorporate alternative choices of parallel collections.  So my recommendation would be `Seq` unless you are pretty sure that you have use-cases where you'd like parallel processing.  If you simply don't care, `Seq` is simpler to reason about for you and for users of the function.