# Iterating immutable Seq, Vector and List: any differences?

Tags: scala

Scala offers so many collections... I am not sure which one to use.

My function generates a collection of a predefined number of elements which are to be iterated one by one by their original order.

All of immutable `Vector`, `Seq` and `List` support iteration, but which one should I use?

Comment: FYI http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/introduction.html and especially http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html

Comment: a very detailed answer can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722137/scala-2-8-collections-design-tutorial

Comment: If your function actually generates the elements it could be worth to return a Stream. This way, only those elements that are actually used are generated which could, depending on your exact use case, reduce some computational overhead.

Comment: @MartinThurau I don't think it is quite good tip for a novice. It is quite easy to misuse Streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a collection which maintains order. Any collection that extends `seq` maintains the order in which elements were added.

[scaladocs]
`Sequences have two principal subtraits, IndexedSeq and LinearSeq, which give different guarantees for performance. An IndexedSeq provides fast random-access of elements and a fast length operation. A LinearSeq provides fast access only to the first element via head, but also has a fast tail operation`

`List` extends `LinearSeq`, while `Vector` extends `IndexedSeq`

Choosing between these will depend on how you wish to access the data, and operations you wish to performs on the data.