# Lost in the inheritance graph of Scala's collections

Tags: scala, inheritance, collections, types, complexity-theory

Today I wanted to learn about the supertypes of `List`:

```
sealed abstract class List[+A] extends AbstractSeq[A]
                                  with LinearSeq[A]
                                  with Product
                                  with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, List]
                                  with LinearSeqOptimized[A, List[A]]
```

Wow, so `List` has already five immediate supertypes. Let's pick one at random:

```
trait LinearSeq[+A] extends Seq[A]
                       with scala.collection.LinearSeq[A]
                       with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, LinearSeq]
                       with LinearSeqLike[A, LinearSeq[A]]
```

Okay, let's pick the one with the most similar name:

```
trait LinearSeqLike[+A, +Repr <: LinearSeqLike[A, Repr]] extends SeqLike[A, Repr]
```

Ah, it seems we're getting somewhere, only one supertype left:

```
trait SeqLike[+A, +Repr] extends Any
                            with IterableLike[A, Repr]
                            with GenSeqLike[A, Repr]
                            with Parallelizable[A, ParSeq[A]]
```

At this point I gave up. How deep does this graph go? Which of all these supertypes are conceptually relevant, and which of them are just implementation details or optimization tricks?

**How does one make sense of such an enormous inheritance graph?**

Comment: Well, first you make sure you have your iron rations, torch, and ten foot pole, and then you descend, poking at things to make sure they are not a trap....  More seriously, the collections hierarchy is huge and most of it actually does something conceptually.  It's not easy.  At least most of the types now explain at the top of their docs what they are for.  (It's about another three or four levels before you bottom out in things like `GenTraversableOnce`.)

Comment: If you are just interested in the user-facing parts of the collection API (or as a warming up for before looking at the internals), a good start is this group of inheritance graphs: http://www.decodified.com/scala/collections-api.xml ; it isn't completely up to date, but fortunately it hasn't become obsolete yet.

Comment: @gourlaysama Those are nice diagrams, but I cannot find `AbstractSeq`, `Product`, `GenericTraversableTemplate`, `LinearSeqOptimized`, `LinearSeqLike`, `SeqLike`, `IterableLike`, `GenSeqLike` or `Parallelizable` in there...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala 2.8 collections design tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722137/scala-2-8-collections-design-tutorial)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most parents are indeed implementation details and optimization tricks. If you don't care about it, you can ignore anything with `Like` or `Template` at the end. Applying that to lists, we have: `List <: LinearSeq <: Seq <: Iterable <: Traversable`. You should use these traits as arguments types in your code (rather than the implementation traits). They are decribed in: [Scala Collections API](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/introduction.html)

If you want to understand how the implementations traits are used, or design your own collections, you should read this tutorial: [The Architecture of Scala Collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html).

Moreover, if you want/need to know where a given method is actually implemented, click on the method signature in the scaladoc to expand de description. The  *Definition Classes* field shows links to the implementation location.

Comment: I found out I learned quite a bit by expanding on the method and look at the *Definition Classes*. For instance for `List.isEmpty` it will show *SeqLike → IterableLike → TraversableLike → TraversableOnce → GenTraversableOnce*. I can then follow `SeqLike` and learn more about it. I can then click on SeqLike.scala and check the source code...

Answer (score 1):

Once you reached the `SeqLike`, you're almost there -- `IterableLike` has just `GenIterableLike` and `TraversableLike` above it, `TraversableLike` only has `TraversableOnce` and `GenTraversableLike` above.

And `TraversableOnce` has `GenTraversableOnce` above it, and that's it :)

The link that the other user provided (also http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html) is a good reference -- you just need to know that each of those types have a corresponding `*Like` type that holds the representation type parameter `Repr`.

But from the point of view of extending collections, you just need to find the most specific type you want to extend in most cases, for example `SeqLike` and extend `Seq[T]` and `Seq[T, YourCollectionType[T]]`.

In the future versions of Scala the `Gen*` traits might be removed, though, making the hierarchy simpler.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [nice overview](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_1.html) of the hierarchy of collection classes over at scala-lang.org.

Comment: Those are nice diagrams, but I cannot find `AbstractSeq`, `Product`, `GenericTraversableTemplate`, `LinearSeqOptimized`, `LinearSeqLike`, `SeqLike`, `IterableLike`, `GenSeqLike` or `Parallelizable` in there...