# Scala: what is trait TraversableOnce? What's the different between TraversableOnce and Traversable?

Tags: scala

TraversableOnce: "A template trait for collections which can be traversed either once only or **one** or **more times**."

I don't understand this sentence. Why can be traversed **more times**? Isn't only **once**? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce) also says

> This trait exists primarily to eliminate code duplication between Iterator and Traversable, and thus implements some of the common methods that can be implemented solely in terms of `foreach` without access to a Builder.

Iterators can only be 'traversed' once. A Traversable can be traversed many times.

Essentially, TraversableOnce is an interface that abstracts away how you handle Iterators and Traversables. Your code could receive either an Iterator or a Traversable and handle them in exactly the same way!

For a good explanation of many of the traits used in the Collections library, I believe the majority (if not all) of [the Scala 2.8 Collections Design Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722137/scala-2-8-collections-design-tutorial) is still correct.

Answer (score 2):

Note that with [Scala 2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0) (June 2019), there is no more `Traversable` and `TraversableOnce`: They remain only as deprecated aliases for `Iterable` and `IterableOnce`. (initially part of the [Collections rework](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2017/02/28/collections-rework.html#traversable-and-iterable))

[`IterableOnce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IterableOnce.html) also has the same sentence:

> A template trait for collections which can be traversed either once only or one or more times.

This time:

> The goal is to provide a minimal interface without any sequential operations.
>   This allows third-party extension like Scala parallel collections to integrate at the level of `IterableOnce` without inheriting unwanted implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are something can only be traversed once, eg:

```
Iterator.continually(readline)
```

The expression will create an iterator, but it can be only traversed once, otherwise it must store all read data, which is a waste in most of the time.

And many container can be traversed as many times as you want, like `Array`, `Map` and so on

If a Traversable can be traversed more than once, it sure can be traversed once. So *all Traversable are also TraversableOnce*, TraversableOnce can be traversed at lease once, but also can be more times.