# In Scala, is there a way to take convert two lists into a Map?

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, scala-2.8, tuples

I have a two lists, a `List[A]` and a `List[B]`. What I want is a `Map[A,B]` but I want the semantics of `zip`. So started out like so:

```
var tuplesOfAB = listOfA zip listOfB
```

Now I'm not sure how to construct a `Map` from my `tuplesOfAB`.

As a follow-up question, I also want to invert my map so that from a `Map[A,B]` I can create a `Map[B,A]`. Can anyone hit me with a clue-stick?

Comment: Thanks for asking this.  I came here to find it.  Now I don't have to ask it myself.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In **2.8** this is really simple using the `CanBuildFrom` functionality ([as described by Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721356/scala-2-8-canbuildfrom)) and using `breakOut` with a type *instruction* to the compiler as to what the result type should be:

```
import scala.collection.breakOut
val m = (listA zip listB)(breakOut): Map[A,B]
```

The following would also work:

```
val n: Map[A,B] = (listA zip listB)(breakOut)
```

And (as EastSun, below, has pointed out) this has been added to the library as `toMap`

```
val o = (listA zip listB).toMap
```

As for reversing the map, you can do:

```
val r = m.map(_.swap)(breakOut): Map[B, A]
```

Comment: Ah! That method does not exist in the build of 2.8 which I have (r20327)

Comment: yes, it was recently added after paulp has shown how easy it was to write it, in response to another question. He then suggested adding it to the lib, since every other major collection was already represented.

Answer (score 15):

Now that you've got a list of tuples it is easy to make it into a map by writing `Map(tuplesOfAB: _*)`. The `: _*` notation means to call the varargs overload with the arguments taken from the sequence. This seems like a funny bit of syntax, but it helps to think that varargs are declared like `Map[A,B](pairs: (A,B)*)` and the `: _*` is a type annotation to convert to varargs because of the common `*` part.

To reverse a map `m` use `Map(m.map(_.swap): _*)`. In scala a map is also a collection of pairs. This transforms those pairs by swapping the elements and passing them to the Map constructor.

Answer (score 6):

There's yet another way to do it, beyond those already shown. Here:

```
Map() ++ tuplesOfAB
```

Answer (score 6):

```
scala> List( "a", "f", "d") zip List(7, 5, 4, 8) toMap
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(a -> 7, f -> 5, d -> 4)
```