# Scala: creating HashMap using two Lists

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming, hashmap

I have two lists in Scala:

```
val workersList = Worker1 :: Worker2 :: Worker3 :: Worker4 :: Nil // type List[Worker]
val workStationsList = WS1 :: WS2 :: WS3 :: WS4 :: Nil // type List[WorkStation]
```

A worker object has a parameter `worksIn : List[WorkStation]`

Knowing that `Worker1` works in `WS1` and `WS2`, `Worker2` works in `WS1` and `WS2`, `Worker3` works in `WS3` and `WS4` and `Worker4` works in `WS3` and `WS4` I want to get a `HashMap[Worker, List[WorkStation]]` that states exactly that.

It's result should be something like this:

```
Worker1 -> List(WS1 :: WS2 :: Nil)
Worker2 -> List(WS1 :: WS2 :: Nil)
Worker3 -> List(WS3 :: WS4 :: Nil)
Worker4 -> List(WS3 :: WS4 :: Nil)
```

I tried to do this, but it doesn't work:

```
val list = workersList.flatMap(w => workStationsList.map(ws => if(w.worksIn.contains(w)) w -> ws)).toMap[Worker, List[WorkStation]]
```

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Scala, is there a way to take convert two lists into a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189784/in-scala-is-there-a-way-to-take-convert-two-lists-into-a-map)

Comment: The real problem is not how to convert the two lists into a HashMap. It's how I can get the result that I want. That answer doesn't help me in my specific problem.

Comment: Not sure what you need the second list for, you can simply do `workersList.map(w => (w, w.worksIn)).toMap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val list = workersList.map(w => (w -> w.worksIn)).toMap // type Map[Worker, List[WorkStation]]
```

`workStationList` seems superfluous.