# Collection type generated by for with yield

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

When I evaluate a `for` in Scala, I get an immutable `IndexedSeq` (a collection with array-like performance characteristics, such as efficient random access):

```
scala> val s = for (i <- 0 to 9) yield math.random + i
s: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Double] = Vector(0.6127056766832756, 1.7137598183155291, ...
```

Does a `for` with a `yield` always return an `IndexedSeq`, or can it also return some other type of collection class (a `LinearSeq`, for example)? If it can also return something else, then what determines the return type, and how can I influence it?

I'm using Scala 2.8.0.RC3.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/can-someone-explain-scalas-yield/1059501#1059501 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721356/scala-2-8-canbuildfrom

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks michael.kebe for your comment.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/can-someone-explain-scalas-yield/1059501#1059501) explains how `for` is translated to operations with `map`, `flatMap`, `filter` and `foreach`. So my example:

```
val s = for (i <- 0 to 9) yield math.random + i
```

is translated to something like this (I'm not sure if it's translated to `map` or `flatMap` in this case):

```
val s = (0 to 9) map { math.random + _ }
```

The result type of operations like `map` on collections depends on the collection you call it on. The type of `0 to 9` is a `Range.Inclusive`:

```
scala> val d = 0 to 9
d: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive with scala.collection.immutable.Range.ByOne = Range(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

The result of the `map` operation on that is an `IndexedSeq` (because of the builder stuff inside the collections library).

So, to answer my question: the result of a `for (...) yield ...` depends on what type is inside the parantheses. If I want a `List` as the result, I could do this:

```
scala> val s = for (i <- List.range(0, 9)) yield math.random + i
s: List[Double] = List(0.05778968639862214, 1.6758775042995566, ...
```

Comment: It's translated to map in your case. If you have a for comprehension with two generators, this is translated into a flatMap/map combination. So for (i <- 0 until 9; j <- 0 until i) yield(i*j) is translated to (0 until 9).flatMap{case i => (0 until i).map{case j=> i*j}}

Comment: "depends on what type is inside the parantheses", more precise its the first right side parameter which determines the type.

Answer (score 6):

You can always transform a range to a list using toList:

```
> val s = for (i <- (0 to 9).toList) yield math.random + i
> s  : List[Double]
```