# How does yield expand to in multiple dimension loop in Scala?

Tags: scala

From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947896/collection-type-generated-by-for-with-yield) we get to know that an expression like:

```
for( i <- 1 to 10 ) yield i + 1
```

will expand into

```
( 1 to 10 ).map( _+1 )
```

But what does the following expression expand to?

```
for( i <- 1 to 50  j <- i to 50 ) yield List(1,i,j)
```

Is this correct?

```
( 1 to 50 ).map( x => (1 to 50 ).map(List(1,x,_))
```

I'm interested in this problem because I'd like to make a function which performs multiple `Xi <- Xi-1 to 50` operations, as shown below:

```
for( X1 <- 1 to 50  X2 <- X1 to 50  X3 <- X2 to 50 ..... Xn <- Xn-1 to 50 ) 
    yield List(1,X1,X2,X3,.....,Xn)
```

The function has one parameter: `dimension` which denotes the `n` in the above expression.
Its return type is `IndexSeq[List[Int]]`

How can I achieve that?

Thank you for answering (:

Answer (score 6):

It's well explained in a relevant [doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html). In particular:

```
for(x <- c1; y <- c2; z <- c3) yield {...}
```

will be translated into

```
c1.flatMap(x => c2.flatMap(y => c3.map(z => {...})))
```

I don't think there is a way to abstract over arbitrary nested comprehension (unless you're using voodoo magic, like macros)

Answer (score 0):

See om-nom-nom's answer for an explanation of what the for loops expand to. I'd like to answer the second part of the opening question, how to implement a function that can do:

```
for( X1 <- 1 to 50  X2 <- X1 to 50  X3 <- X2 to 50 ..... Xn <- Xn to 50 ) 
    yield List(1,X1,X2,X3,.....,Xn)
```

You can use:

```
def upto50(dimension: Int) = {
  def loop(n: Int, start: Int): IndexedSeq[List[Int]] = {
    if (n > dimension)
      IndexedSeq(List())
    else {
      (n to 50).flatMap(x => loop(n + 1, x).map(x :: _))
    }
  }
  loop(1, 1)
}
```

We compute each of the loops recursively, working inside-out, starting with `Xn to 50` and building up the solution.

Solutions for the more general case of:

```
for( X1 <- S1  X2 <- S2  X3 <- S3 ..... Xn <- Sn ) 
    yield List(1,X1,X2,X3,.....,Xn)
```

Where S1..Sn are arbitraray sequences or monads are also possible. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/stephendavidmarsh/1b29d7d9ce81d018307f) for the necessary wall of code.

Comment: I understand that `Vector` is a subtype of `Indexseq`, but why don't you just use `Indexseq` here?

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the output of `upto50` is not incremental as required.  Is it possible to modify it so that it produce "strictly incremental sequence"?  Again, thanks for answering (:

Comment: Oops, I missed that each loop starts from the value of the previous loop. And you're right, `IndexedSeq` makes more sense. Edited.