# Is it possible to know what Scala implicit is being used, without the help of an IDE?

Tags: scala, implicit

For the times when you are reading source code without an IDE at hand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a systematic way to discover which implicit defs are in scope, and which one is bound at a particular point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179415/is-there-a-systematic-way-to-discover-which-implicit-defs-are-in-scope-and-whic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compile with the `Xprint:typer` scalac option.

This tells scalac to explain what it's doing.

[This article](http://pietrowski.info/2009/07/scala-implicit-conversion/) explains the option and gives an example of the output (towards the bottom).