# Implicit parameters break type inference or inference does not suffice for their resolution?

Tags: scala, type-inference, typeclass, implicits

Type inference works fine in this example until I add the implicit ordering evidence. Type inference rules (from left to right & across parameter lists) seem to be satisfied, but there is something in regards to the implicit that breaks it.

```
case class Insert[I, O : Ordering](arg: I)
def execute[I,O](req: Insert[I,O]): O = null.asInstanceOf[O]
val result: Int = execute(Insert("test"))

Error:(5, 39) diverging implicit expansion for type Ordering[O]
starting with method Tuple9 in object Ordering
lazy val result: Int = execute(Insert("test"));}
                                     ^
```

This compiles and works fine:

```
case class Insert[I, O](arg: I)
def execute[I,O](req: Insert[I,O]): O = null.asInstanceOf[O]
val result: Int = execute(Insert("test"))
```

So either type inference isn't sufficient for implicit resolution OR implicit resolution breaks type inference.

I guess the `O` type is inferred but when implicit resolution is happening, it sees it as Nothing, in other words, it sees it as if I didn't specified `Int` in `val result: Int`. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that scala cannot infer the `O` type because it is not present in `Insert`

```
// I is in the parameter list but there is no O to be found
case class Insert[I, O](arg: I)(implicit evidence: Ordering[O])
```

This leaves the compiler no choice but to infer `O` to be `Nothing`. Creating an instance of `Insert` will then fail to compile.

```
scala> val i = Insert(3)
<console>:9: error: diverging implicit expansion for type Ordering[O]
starting with method Tuple9 in object Ordering
   val i = Insert(3)
```

The `diverging implicit expansion` error is scala attempting to find an implicit that works for this case and getting caught in a cycle. It is a red herring.

Comment: Imho the important moment here is the type construction that happens here `val result: Int = execute(Insert("test"))`, anything before is just an type parameter declaration, imho it doesn't matter at all that `O` is not present in `case class Insert[I, O](arg: I)(implicit evidence: Ordering[O])` as a paramter, only the type construction is important here and whether at that time the type `Int` is inferred and because I explicitly specified it, the implicit parameter should be resolved

Comment: My point is that `O` is never inferred to `Int` like you believe it is. `O` is inferred to `Nothing` and your method ends up having a return type of `Nothing`.

Comment: I see your point, so it's rather a question whether type inference works across method invocations, if it transitions from `val i: Int` to `execute` to `Insert` which I think it should, right? AKA "From left to right, across parameter lists", question is whether it also works across method invocations :-)

Comment: I hope you see my point, because this class definition compiles fine `case class Insert[I, O](arg: I)(implicit evidence: Ordering[O])`, until you try to instantiate the type parameters here `val result: Int = execute(Insert("test"))` where the `Int` type IS/SHOULD BE actually inferred

Comment: I understand where you are coming from but I don't agree. I am pretty sure the compiler starts from `Insert("test")`, infers the type of `O` there, and then moves on to the method.

I might be able to help you more with your actual problem (where the implicit should be and how to have it's type inferred). Is there a more concrete example you can provide?

Comment: Here is a comparison of the typechecking internals for the program with and without the implicit parameter:

http://rawgit.com/retronym/22260bca2087f21cfd41/raw/out.html

Without an implicit parameter, the undetermined type variable `O` is inferred as `Nothing` in order to adapt the result type of `execute` to the declared typed `Int`. With the implicit parameter, the implicit search for `Ord[O]` cannot resolves a unique matching implicit, and typechecking fails before considering `Int`.

Comment: Ok, I've been thinking all the time that type inference works from left to right and since Insert is a parameter of execute and `Int` is the leftmost type, it should qualify... There are much more Nothings out there than I can imagine then...Thank you guys