# How can I properly model a node in a non-homogenous, immutable tree?

Tags: scala

I need to model a node in a tree. Node has children, of course, and there is inheritance hierarchy of nodes:

```
trait Node extends Seq[Node] { 
  val children:List[Node] = List()
  def apply(n:Int) = children(n)
  def iterator = children.iterator
  def length = children.length
  def add(n:Node):Node = { ??? }
}
case class NodeA(n:Int) extends Node
case class NodeB(n:String) extends Node
case class NodeC(c:String) extends NodeB(c)

val na:NodeA = new NodeA(1)
val na1:NodeA = na.add(new NodeB("a"))
na1.children == List(NodeB("a"))
val na2:NodeA = na1.add(new NodeC("b"))
na2.children == List(NodeB("a"), NodeC("b"))
```

The problem here is that I want to keep Node and its subclasses immutable.

That's then I begin having problems. How do I write method .add on Node properly? Because obviously calling NodeA.add should return NodeA, not Node.
The collateral damage is that even if I put all Node-specific methods implementations (`children`, `add`, `remove`) into each of subclasses (or into companion objects, builders, CanBuildFrom's, etc), then I'll need to define `children` as a constructor parameter. Which would clutter Node subclasses definition and usage - I should avoid it if possible.

Is this possible? Or am I doing something wrong and there is another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking how to abstract over the return type of `add`? If so, you might want to look into [functional dependencies](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/07/16/fundeps-in-scala/). See also `CanBuildFrom` from the Scala collections, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721356/scala-2-8-canbuildfrom) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout).