# Does the order in Scala for loop influence

Tags: scala

I'm new for Scala. I have a question about the order in the foor loop.

```
type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]

lazy val dictionaryByOccurrences: Map[Occurrences, List[Word]] = dictionary.groupBy(x => wordOccurrences(x))

def wordAnagrams(word: Word): List[Word] = dictionaryByOccurrences.getOrElse(wordOccurrences(word), List())

def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] = occurrences match {
    case List() => List(List())
    case head::tail => {
    for (o <- combinations(tail); x <- 1 to head._2)
    yield (head._1, x) :: o
}
```

if I change the order in the for loop, it will be wrong

```
def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] = occurrences match {
    case List() => List(List())
    case head::tail => {
    for (x <- 1 to head._2; o <- combinations(tail))
    yield (head._1, x) :: o
}
```

I can not find the reason

Answer (score 1):

The type constructor of `for(x <- xs; y <- ys; ...) yield f(x, y, ...)` is the same of `xs` by default. Now the return type of `combinations` is `List[Occurrences]`, then the expected type constructor is `List[_]`, while the type constructor of `1 to n` is `Seq[_]`.

The following codes work:

```
def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] = occurrences match {
    case List() => List(List())
    case head::tail => {
    for (x <- (1 to head._2).toList; o <- combinations(tail))
    yield (head._1, x) :: o
}
```

And this would work too:

```
import collection.breakOut
def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] = occurrences match {
    case List() => List(List())
    case head::tail => {
      (for (x <- 1 to head._2; o <- combinations(tail))
        yield (head._1, x) :: o)(breakOut)
    }
}
```

In depth, `for(x <- xs; y <- ys; ...) yield f(...)` is equivalent to `xs.flatMap(...)`, and the full signature of `List#flatMap` as following:

```
def flatMap[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B])
                    (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

You can see that the return type of `flatMap` is a **magic** `That` which is `List[B]` by default, you can look into [Scala 2.8 CanBuildFrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721356/scala-2-8-canbuildfrom) for more information.