# Understanding String in Scala and the map method

Tags: string, scala, dictionary

I wrote the following simple example to understand how the map method works:

```
object Main{
  def main (args : Array[String]) = {
    val test = "abc"
    val t = Vector(97, 98, 99)
    println(test.map(c => (c + 1)))               //1 Vector(98, 99, 100)
    println(test.map(c => (c + 1).toChar))        //2 bcd
    println(t.map(i => (i + 1)))                  //3 Vector(98, 99, 100)
    println(t.map(i => (i + 1).toChar))           //4 Vector(b, c, d)
  };
}
```

I didn't quite understand why bcd is printed at `//2`. Since every String is treated by Scala as being a `Seq` I thought that `test.map(c => (c + 1).toChar)` should have produced another `Seq`. As `//1` suggests `Vector(b, c, d)`. But as you can see, it didn't. Why? How does it actually work?

Comment: Although it's written in Haskell, it's how I learned FP in Scala - http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#the-functor-typeclass. I would recommend buying and reading https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala. Or, I'd suggest, http://learnyouahaskell.com, which is free online.

Comment: @KevinMeredith are you seriously assuming one needs to learn Haskell to understand how Scala string works?

Comment: I posted as a comment, not an answer, for this reason. To understand `map`, my opinion and experience is that it's worthwhile to understand the basics of Functional Programming first - since `map` is a fundamental of FP.

Comment: @KevinMeredith ... in particular to explain Scala's `CanBuildFrom` which simply doesn't exist in Haskell?

Comment: Not an easy reading, but try http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html

Comment: @VictorMoroz - I found [Programming in Scala, 3rd edition](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_3ed)'s  chapter 25 (The Architecture of Scala Collections) to give a good explanation of `CanBuildFrom`. Also - good point, Victor, on calling me out about `CanBuildFrom`. I should've read the question rather than assume it was about understanding `map` in FP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a feature of Scala collections (String in this case is treated as a collection of characters). The real explanation is quite complex, and involves understanding of typeclasses (I guess, this is why Haskell was mentioned in the comment), but the simple explanation is, well, not quite hard.

The point is, Scala collections library authors tried very hard to avoid code duplication. For example, the `map` function on `String` is actually defined here: `scala.collection.TraversableLike#map`. On the other hand, a naive approach to such task would make `map` return `TraversableLike`, not the original type the `map` was called on (it was the `String`). That's why they've came up with an approach that allows to avoid both code duplication and unnecessary type casting or too general return type.

Basically, Scala collections methods like `map` produce the type that is as close to the type it was called at as possible. This is achieved using a typeclass called `CanBuildFrom`. The full signature of the `map` looks as follows:

```
def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That
```

There is a lot of explanations what is a typeclass and `CanBuildFrom` around. I'd suggest looking here first: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html#factoring-out-common-operations. Another good explanation is here: [Scala 2.8 CanBuildFrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721356/scala-2-8-canbuildfrom)

Comment: The example of that is, even if the test was declared as a Seq[Char] it is still converted to a String

Comment: +1 The really short answer is that Scala's collection operations are type-preserving like Smalltalk's, not most-general-type-always like Java's, .NET's (`IEnumerable`) or Ruby's (`Array`).

Answer (score 0):

When you use map, this is what is happening : `[List|Seq|etc].map([eachElement] => [do something])`

map applies some operation to each element of the variable on the left hand-side : `"abc".map(letter => letter + 1)` will add 1 to each element of the `String` "abc". And each element of the `String` `abc` is called here "letter" (which is of type `Char`)

"abc" is a String, and as in C++, it is treated as an array of characters. But since `test` is of type String, the map function gives a String as well.

I tried the following :

```
val test2 : Seq[Char] = "abc"
```

but I still get a result of type String, I guess Scala does the conversion automatically from a Seq[Char] to a String

I hope it helped!