# How to merge two Seq[String], Seq[Double] to Seq[(String,Double)]

Tags: scala, seq

I have two Seq.
1 has `Seq[String]` and another has `Seq[(String,Double)]`

`a -> ["a","b","c"]` and 
`b-> [1,2,3]`

I want to create output as

```
[("a",1),("b",2),("c",3)]
```

I have a code
`a.zip(b)` is actually creating a seq of those two elements instead of creating a map

Can anyone suggest how to do that in scala?

Comment: `a.zip(b).toMap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you simply need `.toMap` so that you can transform `List[Tuple[String, Int]]` to `Map[String, Int]`

```
scala> val seq1 = List("a", "b", "c")
seq1: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> val seq2 = List(1, 2, 3)
seq2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> seq1.zip(seq2)
res0: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,2), (c,3))

scala> seq1.zip(seq2).toMap
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3)
```

### also see

[How to convert a Seq[A] to a Map[Int, A] using a value of A as the key in the map?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925643/432903)