# How do I convert a Map[Int, Any] to a SortedMap in Scala? Or a TreeMap?

Tags: scala

I would like to convert a `Map[Int, Any]` to a `SortedMap` or a `TreeMap`.  Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Assuming you're using immutable maps

```
val m = Map(1 -> "one")
val t = scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap(m.toArray:_*)
```

The `TreeMap` companion object's apply method takes repeated map entry parameters (which are instances of `Tuple2[_, _]` of the appropriate parameter types). `toArray` produces an `Array[Tuple2[Int, String]]` (in this particular case). The `: _*` tells the compiler that the array's contents are to be treated as repeated parameters.

Comment: This is a correct answer. But it shows an ugly side of the scala collections: it is too awkward.

Comment: Is this going to push the entire contents of m onto the stack as method arguments? Or is Scala/Java smarter than that?

Comment: This solution is inefficient, as it first copies the entire copies of the `Map` to an array, and then copies the array into a `TreeMap.Builder`.

Answer (score 49):

An alternative to using `:_*` as described by sblundy is to append the existing map to an empty `SortedMap`

```
import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap
val m = Map(1 -> ("one":Any))
val sorted = SortedMap[Int, Any]() ++ m
```

Comment: How does this compare to the other options in terms of performance?

Comment: i would write that as `val sorted = SortedMap.empty[Int,Any] ++ m` since as written it reads like it is constructing a wasted empty map although hopefully the compiler is smart enough not to.

Answer (score 34):

Here's a general way to convert between various Scala collections.

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import collection.immutable.TreeMap

object test {
  class TraversableW[A](t: Traversable[A]) {
    def as[CC[X] <: Traversable[X]](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, CC[A]]): CC[A] = t.map(identity)(collection.breakOut)
    def to[Result](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, Result]): Result = t.map(identity)(collection.breakOut)
  }

  implicit def ToTraverseableW[A](t: Traversable[A]): TraversableW[A] = new TraversableW[A](t)

  List(1, 2, 3).as[Vector]
  List(1, 2, 3).to[Vector[Int]]
  List((1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 4)).to[Map[Int, Int]]
  List((1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 4)).to[TreeMap[Int, Int]]
  val tm: TreeMap[Int, Int] = List((1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 4)).to
  ("foo": Seq[Char]).as[Vector]
}

test
```

See also this question describing `collection.breakOut`: [Scala 2.8 breakOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout)

**CHALLENGE**

Is it possible to adjust the implicits such that this works? Or would this only be possible if `as` were added to `Traversable`?

```
"foo".as[Vector]
```

Comment: You can make the implicit receive a view bound instead of a Traversable, but I can't think of a way to retrieve "A" from that. After all, `String` doesn't have an "A".

Comment: I had the same problem. The `A` should be `Char`. Similar problem for retrieving `(Int, Int)` as the element type of a Map.

Comment: @retronym - really appreciate your post on my simple "scala newbie" question.  Sent me on a good dive with the link you posted on collection.breakout.

Comment: IttayD: I suspect that solves a slightly different problem, but need to look at it more closely. Thanks!

Comment: I think this conversation (http://www.scala-lang.org/node/5677) and bug (https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3201) are relevant. I ran into them coming at this problem from a slightly different angle: http://gist.github.com/445874

Comment: Assuming the contest is still open, here is how I would do it: http://ideone.com/pVZVW

Comment: As-of at least Scala 2.12, the collections have a predefined `to` method that does what this `as` does, and also creates a naming conflict that will give a compiler error _{target type} takes no type parameters, expected: one_.

The fix is to eliminate the `as` method given above and rename `to` to `as` so the names don't collide.

Answer (score 15):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, via factory builders applied with [`.to(factory)`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#to[C1](factory:scala.collection.Factory[A,C1]):C1):

```
Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b").to(collection.immutable.SortedMap)
// collection.immutable.SortedMap[Int,String] = TreeMap(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
```

```scala
Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b").to(collection.immutable.TreeMap)
// collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int,String] = TreeMap(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way you can do it with a Scala implicit class:

```
implicit class ToSortedMap[A,B](tuples: TraversableOnce[(A, B)])
                               (implicit ordering: Ordering[A]) {
  def toSortedMap =
    SortedMap(tuples.toSeq: _*)
}
```

Since Map[A,B] has an implicit path to a TraversableOnce[Tuple2[A, B]], the following works:

```
scala> Map("b" -> 3, "c" -> 3, "a" -> 5).toSortedMap
res6: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[String,Int] = Map(a -> 5, b -> 3, c -> 3)
```

It will even work on a list of Tuple2s, similar to toMap:

```
scala> List(("c", 1), ("b", 3),("a", 6)).toSortedMap
res7: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[String,Int] = Map(a -> 6, b -> 3, c -> 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since internal data structures in implementations are completely different, you'll have to add elements one-by-one anyway. So, do it explicitly:

```
val m = Map(1 -> "one")

var t = scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int,String]()
t ++= m
```