# Initializing a scala BitSet from a range

Tags: scala

I'd like to initialize a scala BitSet to contain the integers from 1 to N.  The following will work, but I'm looking for a better solution:

```
var s = BitSet.empty ++ (1 to n)
```

I was hoping that I could do something like this:

```
var s:BitSet = (1 to n).toSet
```

...but that results in an error:

```
error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
  found   : [B >: Int]scala.collection.immutable.Set[B]
  required: scala.collection.immutable.BitSet
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I like the first solution. It's pretty impressive how it works underneath too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thats what `breakOut` is for:

```
val s: BitSet = (1 to n).map(identity)(breakOut)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout) to understand the inner working of breakOut.

Another solution is to use the constructor of BitSet:

```
val s = BitSet((1 to n): _*)
```

the `: _*` tells the compiler that you want to use the Range as repeated parameters.

Because `breakOut` looks ugly you can use the pimp-my-library pattern to produce nicer looking code (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074118/scala-how-do-i-convert-a-mapint-any-to-a-sortedmap-or-a-treemap)):

```
val s = (1 to n).to[BitSet]
```

Answer (score 3):

Digging into the Scala source code, the definition of toBitSet is in TraversibleOnce.scala:

```
/** Converts this $coll to a set.
 *  $willNotTerminateInf
 *  @return      a set containing all elements of this $coll.
 */
def toSet[B >: A]: immutable.Set[B] = immutable.Set() ++ self
```

So, interestingly enough, the Scala implementation of toSet is basically just doing your first solution behind the scenes in the case of a plain Set.  If you really would strongly prefer the second syntax you suggested for the case of a BitSet, then you could roll your own with an implicit type conversion:

```
class BitSetConvertible(t: TraversableOnce[Int]) {
  def toBitSet = BitSet.empty ++ t
}

implicit def asBitSetConvertible(t: TraversableOnce[Int]) = new BitSetConvertible(t)
```

With that in place, you can now make statements like:

```
val s = 1 to 10 toBitSet
```