# BitSet to Set[Int] or vice versa in Scala

Tags: scala, set, bitset

I have a library that uses BitSet, and I need to change Set[Int] type data to use the library.

What comes to mind is to use `.toSeq:_*` operations, but I'm not sure this is efficient way to convert from BitSet to Set[Int] or the other way round.

```
scala> BitSet(Set(1,2,3).toSeq:_*)
res55: scala.collection.immutable.BitSet = BitSet(1, 2, 3)

scala> Set(BitSet(1,2,3).toSeq:_*)
res56: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: For the second, `.toSet` or `.seq` should work

Comment: Maybe [Initializing a scala BitSet from a range](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6366976/1048572) is of help for the first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala's `Set` hierarchy is a little weird, but it is the case that `BitSet` has `Set[Int]` as a super type, so you can simply pass a `BitSet` to a method that expects a `Set[Int]`, etc.

This might not seem to be the case because the `Set` you get by default is `immutable.Set` (under `scala.collection`), while it's possible that the library you're using is working with the `BitSet` directly under `scala.collection`, not `immutable.BitSet`. This isn't the case in your example code, where everything is in `immutable`, but I'm not sure how simplified that is.

If you're lucky enough to be working with the `immutable` package's versions of both `Set` and `BitSet`, the `BitSet` to `Set` direction is trivial:

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.BitSet
import scala.collection.immutable.BitSet

scala> val bs = BitSet(0, 100, 200)
bs: scala.collection.immutable.BitSet = BitSet(0, 100, 200)

scala> def takesSet(s: Set[Int]): Int = s.size
takesSet: (s: Set[Int])Int

scala> takesSet(bs)
res0: Int = 3
```

If somehow you've got a `scala.collection.BitSet`, just use `toSet`:

```
scala> takesSet(scala.collection.BitSet(0, 100, 200).toSet)
res1: Int = 3
```

For the other direction, your version is fine:

```
scala> val s = Set(1, 2, 3)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> BitSet(s.toSeq: _*)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.BitSet = BitSet(1, 2, 3)
```

But it's also worth noting that in many cases you can avoid this conversion with some `CanBuildFrom` magic:

```
scala> val bs: BitSet = Set("1", "2", "3").map(_.toInt)(collection.breakOut)
bs: scala.collection.immutable.BitSet = BitSet(1, 2, 3)
```

This produces the same result as the following:

```
scala> val bs: BitSet = BitSet(Set("1", "2", "3").map(_.toInt).toSeq: _*)
bs: scala.collection.immutable.BitSet = BitSet(1, 2, 3)
```

But instead of constructing an intermediate set (and sequence) before the `BitSet`, the `collection.breakOut` parameter tells the compiler to perform the map using an instance of the `CanBuildFrom` type class that will construct the `BitSet` directly. Passing a `CanBuildFrom` instance explicitly in this way isn't just for `map`, either—it'll work with `flatMap`, `scanLeft`, `++`, and other collections operations that allow you to change the element type.

Comment: I thought I'd share that:  doing the breakout thing in scala 2.11.12 result in an IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)

Answer (score 0):

Think object-oriented: `BitSet` *is* a `Set[Int]`, you don't need to do anything to convert one to the other:

```
     import scala.collection._
     val set: Set[Int] = BitSet(1,2,3)
```

Going the other way is harder, and will take linear time:

```
     val bs: BitSet = BitSet(set.toStream:_*)
```

but whenever you find yourself needing this kind of "upconverting", 99% of the time it is a sign of bad design, than should be improved to eliminate the need: the implementation details of the particular `Set` should only matter to the code that creates it initially, downstream code should usually be agnostic of the implementation.

Comment: I think that "99%" is hugely optimistic. It'll often be the case that you need to work with `BitSet`s (either because of a third-party API or because you need `BitSet`-specific operations), and it'll often be the case that you need to "lower" ordinary sets into the `BitSet` subtype to make that possible.

Comment: @TravisBrown maybe, I am an optimist :) I am just finding it hard to think of a use case, where I would need a bit set, that _I have not created_. I am sure there are some, just saying I think they are nearly not as often as when people just do these conversions back-and-forth without thinking about whether they really need it. The fact, that `Set` you get from `Predef` is `scala.collection.immutable.Set` and not `scala.collection.Set` also doesn't help IMHO.