# Convert Seq to ArrayBuffer

Tags: scala, seq, arraybuffer

Is there any concise way to convert a `Seq` into `ArrayBuffer` in Scala?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074118/scala-how-do-i-convert-a-mapint-any-to-a-sortedmap-or-a-treemap

Answer (score 28):

```
scala> val seq = 1::2::3::Nil
seq: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> seq.toBuffer
res2: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)
```

**EDIT** After Scala 2.1x, there is a method `.to[Coll]` defined in [TraversableLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableLike), which can be used as follow:

```
scala> import collection.mutable
import collection.mutable

scala> seq.to[mutable.ArrayBuffer]
res1: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)

scala> seq.to[mutable.Set]
res2: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: +1 `seq.toBuffer` has got to be the clearest and most memorable way

Answer (score 12):

This will work:

```
ArrayBuffer(mySeq : _*)
```

Some explanations: this uses the apply method in the [ArrayBuffer companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer%24). The signature of that method is

```
def apply [A] (elems: A*): ArrayBuffer[A]
```

meaning that it takes a variable number of arguments. For instance:

```
ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

is also a valid call. The ascription : _* indicates to the compiler that a Seq should be used in place of that variable number of arguments (see Section 4.6.2 in the [Scala Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)).