# Convert map to HashMap and apply transforms

Tags: scala, type-conversion, scala-collections

I have a java map, `stringMap`, where the keys are strings that represent dates and the values are longs. I need to convert this map into a `collection.mutable.HashMap[DateTime, Long]` That is, in addition to changing the type of map, I need to change from Strings to DateTimes.

This is the solution I am currently using:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
val stringMap: java.util.HashMap[String, Long] = ...
val dateTimeMap = stringMap map { case (k, v) => (df.parseDateTime(k), v)}
val result = collection.mutable.HashMap[DateTime, Long](dateTimeMap.toArray:_*)
```

The last line comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074118/how-do-i-convert-a-mapint-any-to-a-sortedmap-in-scala-or-a-treemap)

Note there is an implicit conversion converting stringMap to a scala Hashmap.

The question is this, is there a better way to do this? I tried using a for yield / the map method with breakout, but they were returning a Map instead of a `collection.mutable.HashMap` EDIT: Apparently breakout does work.
/EDIT

Preferably there would be a functional programming way to do this without the need for a temporary `dateTimeMap`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's advisable to use `JavaConverters` instead to get an explicit conversion to avoid accidentally converting multiple times.

You should be able to use `breakOut` on `map` by specifying the expected result type:

```
import scala.collection.breakOut
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val stringMap: java.util.HashMap[String, Long] = new java.util.HashMap()
stringMap.put("1", 1L)
stringMap.put("2", 2L)

val result: collection.mutable.HashMap[Int, Long] = stringMap.asScala.map { case (k, v) => (k.toInt, v) }(breakOut)
// result: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Long] = Map(2 -> 2, 1 -> 1)
```

Comment: So it turns out if you do this exact same thing, except try to use an implicit conversion instead of asScala, it doesn't work. Unfortunately the style convention for the project I'm working on is to use implicit conversions rather than use any explicit conversions. Is there a way to make this work while adhering to their style conventions?

Comment: The implicit version works for me.  Just replace `JavaConverters` with `JavaConversions` and drop the `.asScala` and it should work.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I tried replacing the dot before `map` with a space. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question if this should work.

```
  val result = collection.mutable.HashMap[DateTime, Long](stringMap.map{ case (k,v) => (df.parseDateTime(k),v)}.toArray:_* )
```

Comment: This solution basically just makes the dateTimeMap without ever giving it a name. I was hoping to not have to make this temporary map, just to throw it away a second later. I was hoping to skip making this temporary map and go straight to creating the result map.

Comment: @KevinWheeler - oh okay. I guess dhg solution above should work then?