# Scala for-comprehension returning an ordered map

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

How can I use a for-comprehension that returns something I can assign to an ordered Map? This is a simplification of the code I have:

```
class Bar
class Foo(val name: String, val bar: Bar)
val myList: java.util.List[Foo] = ...
val result: ListMap[String, Bar] =
    for {
        foo <- myList
    } yield (foo.name, foo.bar)
```

I need to make sure my result is an ordered Map, in the order tuples are returned from the for-comprehension.

With the above, I get the error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[(String,Bar)]
required: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[String,Bar]
foo <- myList
```

This compiles:

```
class Bar
class Foo(val name: String, val bar: Bar)
val myList: java.util.List[Foo] = ...
val result: Predef.Map[String, Bar] =
    {
        for {
            foo <- myList
        } yield (foo.name, foo.bar)
    } toMap
```

but then I assume the map won't be ordered, and I need an explicit toMap call.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve do it by using the companion object of ListMap class as followings:

```
class Bar
class Foo(val name: String, val bar: Bar)
val myList: java.util.List[Foo] = ...
val result = ListMap((for(foo <- myList) yield (foo.name, foo.bar)):_*)
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the appending :\_\* means?

Comment: I case you never figured it out; It's just special syntax for saying "insert this stuff into a method that takes vargs", i.e. `public void foo(String ...)`

Answer (score 7):

The **collection.breakOut** is your good friend in such a case,

```
val result: collection.immutable.ListMap[String, Bar] = 
  myList.map{ foo => (foo.name, foo.bar) }(collection.breakOut)
```

If it is important to use for-comprehension expression, it will be done as follows,

```
val result: collection.immutable.ListMap[String, Bar] = {
  for { foo <- myList } yield (foo.name, foo.bar)
}.map(identity)(collection.breakOut)
```

[Scala 2.8 breakOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681) has explained **collection.breakOut** very well.

Comment: I tried with and without .map(identity) and both seem to compile fine. Is there a difference between using .map(identity) or not?

Comment: In the first case, ListMap will be generated from myList directly,
but the latter will generate a seq from myList and then generate ListMap from it.