# How to read from csv to a ListMap

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark

I have been assigned with the task of reading from csv, and creating a ListMap variable. The reason to use this specific class is that for some other use cases they were already using a number of methods with ListMap as input parameter, and they want one more.

What I have done so far is: read from the csv, and create a rdd. 
The format of the csv is

```
"field1,field2"
"value1,value2"
"value3,value4"
```

In this rdd I have tuples of strings. What I would like is to now convert this to a ListMap class. So what I have is a variable with the type **Array[(value1,value2),(value3,value4)]**.

I did this because I find it easy to go from a csv to tuples. The problem is I do not find any way to go from here to a ListMap. It seems easier to get a normal Map class, but as I said, it is required for the final result to be a ListMap type of object.

I have been reading but I do not really understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3828197/6028947) nor [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28957698/6028947)

Comment: is your csv file a space delimited?

Comment: it is separated by "," by which I mean, each line, the fields are separated by the "," character. And each line ends in a "\n"

Comment: is my edit of input csv data in your question correct? if yes are there " (inverted commas) in your data?

Comment: can you share your codes too if possible?

Comment: Yes there are inverted commas. Sometimes the strings are strings and sometimes they have inverted commas. I am trying to show some code but since I am changing it so often to try different cases and working with teammates I'm afraid I do not have something worth showing right now :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the sample data you provided, you can use `collectAsMap` api to get the final `ListMap`

```
val rdd  = sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile("path to the text file")
  .map(line => line.split(","))
  .map(array => array(0) -> array(1))
  .collectAsMap()
```

Thats it.

Now if you want to go a step further you can do additional step as

```
  var listMap : ListMap[String, String] = ListMap.empty[String, String]
  for(map <- rdd) {
    listMap += map
  }
```

Comment: I ended up using both answers, and they both were incredibly helpful. Any advice on how to reflect that? I guess there is a meta post talking about this issue, there always is haha

Answer (score 1):

`Array("foo" -> "bar", "baz" -> "bat").toMap` gives you a `Map`. 
If you are looking for a `ListMap` specifically (for the life of me, can't think of a reason why you would), then you need a `breakOut`:

```
 val map: ListMap[String, String] = 
    Array("foo" -> "bar", "baz" -> "bat")
     .toMap
     .map(identity)(scala.collection.breakOut)
```

`breakOut` is sort of a "collection factory" that lets you implicitly convert between different collection types. You can read more about it here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/breakout.html

Comment: Ooooh so that is what breakOut is. Btw I do not know either. I hope to have time to have it explained to me one of this days... More importantly, I wanted to say I sadly wrote the question wrong. When I read a csv what I get is RDD[(String,String)]. My idea at this point is to collect said RDD, to get an array, and then be able to do what you have taught me. But I have this feeling about how aaaaaaaaall of this is doing it wrong (on my part).

Comment: It's not "wrong" (except, maybe, for the part of using spark for this in the first place), as long as it fits into memory. And if you want to end up with a single  `Map` in the end, it better do :)

Comment: So Spark is the wrong tool for this, right? I was just talking about this the other day. Hive or Impala would make more sense I assume. Since it's a file we could store straight up in hdfs. What other choices would be recommended for a problem similar to this? And yeah, thanks for the warning about the memory and the map issue. I did look previously into it, it seems to be, for now, a small amount of info, because I was very worried about doing collect()

Comment: You don't need hive (or even hdfs) either. Just drop a file on disk, and read it directly.

Comment: But to read it you would need some tool right? In this case if the development is being done with spark and scala, does it makes sense to use them, or there is an easier way to incorporate them to the workflow which I am not aware of (which is the more likely possibility haha)?

Comment: `Source.fromFile("filename.csv").getLines`