# How do I convert Array[Node] to NodeSeq?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, lift

I'm trying to integrate a Lift application into some existing Java code.  In one of my snippets, I have an Array of Java objects that I need to map that into a NodeSeq.  I can get an Array of Node's, but not a NodeSeq.  (At least, not in very functional-looking way).

```
import scala.xml.NodeSeq

// pretend this is code I can't do anything about
val data = Array("one", "two", "three")

// this is the function I need to write
def foo: NodeSeq = data.map { s => <x>{s}</x> }
//                          ^
// error: type mismatch;
//  found   : Array[scala.xml.Elem]
//  required: scala.xml.NodeSeq
```

What's the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: You always have the `++` method available :-) `new NodeSeq() ++ theArray_Elm_thing`. There may be better ways. Happy coding.

Comment: NodeSeq is abstract, so 'new NodeSeq()' doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would simply convert `map` output to sequence (given that `Seq[Node]` is a super-class of `NodeSeq`)

```
scala> def foo: NodeSeq = data.map { s => <x>{s}</x> } toSeq
foo: scala.xml.NodeSeq
```

or use `foldLeft` instead of `map`

```
scala> def foo: NodeSeq = (Seq[Node]() /: data) {(seq, node)=> seq ++ <x>{node}</x>}
foo: scala.xml.NodeSeq
```

Comment: toSeq is the elegance I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: Using map and then toSeq means you're creating 2 collections. Using breakOut you're creating 1.

Comment: `toSeq` creates a wrapper(http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray.html), so there's a miserable performance penalty. http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_38.html

Answer (score 10):

```
scala> import collection.breakOut
import collection.breakOut

scala> def foo: NodeSeq = data.map { s => <x>{s}</x> }(breakOut)
foo: scala.xml.NodeSeq
```

The method map actually has two argument lists. The first accepts a function, which you passed. The second accepts a CanBuildFrom object which is used to create a builder that then builds the returning sequence. This argument is implicit, so usually the compiler fills it for you. It accepts 3 type parameters: From, T, To. There are several predef implicits (including in object NodeSeq), but none of them matches From=Array, T=Node, To=NodeSeq.

breakOut solves this: it is a generic method that returns a CanBuildFrom instance by searching for an implicit CanBuildFrom[Nothing, T, To]. According to the implicit search rules, any CanBuildFrom that matches T, To and has From > Nothing is acceptable. In this case: canBuildFrom in object Array

Comment: It seemed appropriate to link to the breakOut question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for this method on the NodeSeq companion object.

```
NodeSeq.fromSeq(s: Seq[Node])
```