# Yield String from List[Char]

Tags: scala, yield, yield-return

I have a l: List[Char] of characters which I want to concat and return as a String in one for loop.

I tried this

```
val x: String = for(i <- list) yield(i)
```

leading to

```
 error: type mismatch;  
 found   : List[Char]  
 required: String
```

So how can I change the result type of yield?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use the for comprehension for that?

Answer (score 79):

Try this:

```
val x: String = list.mkString
```

This syntax:

```
for (i <- list) yield i
```

is syntactic sugar for:

```
list.map(i => i)
```

and will thus return an unchanged copy of your original `list`.

Comment: @soc: This is indeed possible with scalaz: `(List("a", "b", "c") ∑) assert_≟ "abc"`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
val x: String = (for(i <- list) yield(i))(collection.breakOut)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout) for more information about breakOut.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the three mkString overloads. Basically it converts a collection into a flat String by each element's toString method. Overloads add custom separators between each element.

It is a Iterable's method, so you can also use it in Map or Set.

See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.2/scala/Iterable.html for more details.