# Why does Scala maintain the type of collection not return Iterable (as in .Net)?

Tags: scala, collections

In Scala, you can do

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3)
l.filter(_ > 2)               // returns a List[Int]
val s = Set("hello", "world")
s.map(_.length)               // returns a Set[Int]
```

The question is: why is this useful?

Scala collections are probably the only existing collection framework that does this. Scala community seems to agree that this functionality is needed. Yet, noone seems to miss this functionality in the other languages. Example C# (modified naming to match Scala's):

```
var l = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }
l.filter(i => i > 2)          // always returns Iterable[Int]
l.filter(i => i > 2).toList   // if I want a List, no problem
l.filter(i => i > 2).toSet    // or I want a Set
```

In .NET, I always get back an Iterable and it is up to me what I want to do with it. (This also makes .NET collections very simple) .

<strike>The Scala example with Set forces me to make a Set of lengths out of a Set of string. But what if I just want to iterate over the lengths, or construct a List of lengths, or keep the Iterable to filter it later. Constructing a Set right away seems pointless.</strike> (**EDIT**: collection.view provides the simpler .NET functionality, nice)

I am sure you will show me examples where the .NET approach is absolutely wrong or kills performance, but I just can't see any (using .NET for years).

Comment: "This makes the .NET collections very simple" I would call it broken. When you do some operations on a `List` why shouldn't it return a `List`? Would you recommend that `list.remove(1)` also returns an `Iterable`? => Different opinions. Maybe you could make the question a bit less argumentative?

Comment: An interresting thing to notice in the first example is that `s.map(_.length)` returns a `Set` containing only one element (the integer 5), since "hello" and "world" both have a length of 5.

Comment: @soc - I see, List with 1 removed should be a List, right? Using map of filter, it is not so clear which approach is better. Anyway, I can just use views when needed, so problem solved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not a full answer to your question, but Scala never *forces* you to use one collection type over another. You're free to write code like this:

```
import collection._
import immutable._

val s = Set("hello", "world")
val l: Vector[Int] = s.map(_.length)(breakOut)
```

Read more about `breakOut` in [Daniel Sobral's detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout/1716558#1716558) to another question.

If you want your `map` or `filter` to be evaluated lazily, use this:

```
s.view.map(_.length)
```

This whole behavior makes it easy to integrate your new collection classes and inherit all the powerful capabilities of the standard collection with no code duplication, all of this ensuring that `YourSpecialCollection#filter` returns an instance of `YourSpecialCollection`; that `YourSpecialCollection#map` returns an instance of `YourSpecialCollection` if it supports the type being mapped to, or a built-in fallback collection if it doesn't (like what happens of you call `map` on a `BitSet`). Surely, a C# iterator has no `.toMySpecialCollection` method.

See also: “Integrating new sets and maps” in [The Architecture of Scala Collections](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html).

Comment: Thanks, views almost fully answer my question. I will still wait a bit to see if anyone answers why always returning the same type of collection is the sensible default. Maybe it is just a question of taste though.

Comment: "a C# iterator has no .toMySpecialCollection" - you can use pimp my library pattern (called Extension methods in C#). Extension methods do not involve an extra allocation per call.

Comment: @Martin Note that using views and lazy iterators frequently, especially in a chained way, can be detrimental to performance for small collections, where creating the intermediate collection often isn't very costly. And thanks for the hint on extension methods! Note that on modern JVMs with escape analysis, Scala's pimp-my-library pattern will not cause an extra allocation.

Comment: I accept this answer because it showed me that features of Scala collections are actually a superset of the features of .NET collections.

Answer (score 10):

Scala follows the "uniform return type principle" assuring that you always end up with the appropriate return type, instead of loosing that information like in C#.

The reason C# does it this was is that their type system is not good enough to provide these assurances without overriding the whole implementation of every method in every single subclass. Scala solves this with the usage of Higher Kinded Types.

Why Scala has the only collection framework doing this? Because it is harder than most people think it is, especially when things like Strings and Arrays which are no "real" collections should be integrated as well:

```
// This stays a String:
scala> "Foobar".map(identity)
res27: String = Foobar
// But this falls back to the "nearest" appropriate type:
scala> "Foobar".map(_.toInt)
res29: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(70, 111, 111, 98, 97, 114)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have a `Set`, and an operation on it returns an `Iterable` while its runtime type is still a `Set`, then you're losing important informations about its behavior, and the access to set-specific methods.

BTW: There **are** other languages behaving similar, like Haskell, which influenced Scala a lot. The Haskell version of `map` would look like this translated to Scala (without `implicit`magic):

```
//the functor type class
trait Functor[C[_]] {
   def fmap[A,B](f: A => B, coll: C[A]) : C[B]
}

//an instance  
object ListFunctor extends Functor[List] {
   def fmap[A,B](f: A => B, list: List[A]) : List[B] = list.map(f)
}

//usage 
val list = ListFunctor.fmap((x:Int) => x*x, List(1,2,3))
```

And I think the Haskell community values this feature as well :-)

Answer (score 4):

It is a matter of consistency. Things are what they are, and return things like them. You can depend on it.

The difference you make here is one of strictness. A strict method is immediately evaluated, while a non-strict method is only evaluated as needed. This has consequences. Take this simple example:

```
def print5(it: Iterable[Int]) = {
    var flag = true
    it.filter(_ => flag).foreach { i =>
        flag = i < 5
        println(i)
    }
}
```

Test it with these two collections:

```
print5(List.range(1, 10))
print5(Stream.range(1, 10))
```

Here, `List` is strict, so its methods are strict. Conversely, `Stream` is non-strict, so its methods are non-strict.

So this isn't really related to `Iterable` at all -- after all, both `List` and `Stream` *are* `Iterable`. Changing the collection return type can cause all sort of problems -- at the very least, it would make the task of keeping a persistent data structure harder.

On the other hand, there are advantages to delaying certain operations, even on a strict collection. Here are some ways of doing it:

```
// Get an iterator explicitly, if it's going to be used only once
def print5I(it: Iterable[Int]) = {
    var flag = true
    it.iterator.filter(_ => flag).foreach { i =>
        flag = i < 5
        println(i)
    }
}

// Get a Stream explicitly, if the result will be reused
def print5S(it: Iterable[Int]) = {
    var flag = true
    it.toStream.filter(_ => flag).foreach { i =>
        flag = i < 5
        println(i)
    }
}

// Use a view, which provides non-strictness for some methods
def print5V(it: Iterable[Int]) = {
    var flag = true
    it.view.filter(_ => flag).foreach { i =>
        flag = i < 5
        println(i)
    }
}

// Use withFilter, which is explicitly designed to be used as a non-strict filter
def print5W(it: Iterable[Int]) = {
    var flag = true
    it.withFilter(_ => flag).foreach { i =>
        flag = i < 5
        println(i)
    }
}
```