# What is the best way to create map in parallel with scala?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, scala-collections

Suppose I have a collection which should be converted to Map, but not in one to one fashion like map method.

```
var map = collection.mutable.HashMap()
for (p <- dataList.par) {
  if(cond1(p)) {
    map += (p, true)
  } else {
    // do nothing
  }
}
```

I've come up with several solutions and want to know what is best.

1. `map.synchronize { map += (p, true) }`
2. use actor to update map. But I dont know how to wait till all actors task are completed
3. `yield Some(p) or None` and then run `foreach { case Some(p) => map += (p, true)}`. But I don't know how to make it sequential if first iterator is from parallel collections.

Comment: You can take a look at my (experimental) par stream implementation: https://github.com/aloiscochard/scalax-parstream ... it use Actor as queue behind the cover.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure that will actually perform best, but that should make evaluation of conditions parallel:

```
import scala.collection._
val map: mutable.Map[Int, Boolean] 
  = dataList.par.collect{case p if cond1(p) => (p, true)}(breakOut)
```

(with a mutable Map as it is what your code did, but this is not required).

Context must give the type of the expected result (hence the `: mutable.Map[Int, Boolean]`) for `breakOut` to work.

**Edit:**  `breakOut` is `scala.collection.breakOut`. Collections operation returning a collection (here `collect`) takes an implicit argument `bf: CanBuildFrom[SourceCollectionType, ElementType, ResultType]`. Implicit `CanBuildFroms` made available by the library  are arranged so that the best possible ResultType will be returned, and best means closest to the source collection type. breakOut is passed in place of this implicit argument, so that another `CanBuildFrom`, hence result type, can be selected. What `breakOut` does is select the `CanBuildFrom` irrespective of the source collection type. But then there are many implicits available and no priority rule. That is why the result type must be given by the context, so that one of the implicits can be selected.

To sum up, when `breakOut` is passed in place of the implicit argument, the result will be built to the type expected in the context.

Comment: What do you mean by `breakOut` varible?

Comment: @yura: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout/1716558#1716558

Comment: Completed the answer, see Edit

Comment: Or rather see Daniel Sobral answer, as suggested by Alexey, way better.

Answer (score 6):

The `breakOut` mentioned in the other answer resolves to a builder factory for the collection of the expected type of `map`. The expected type of `map` is `mutable.Map[Int, Boolean]`.

Since the builder factory is provided by a sequential collection, the `collect` will not proceed in parallel:

```
scala> val cond1: Int => Boolean = _ % 2 == 0
cond1: Int => Boolean = <function1>

scala> val dataList = 1 to 10
dataList: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> val map: mutable.Map[Int,Boolean] = dataList.par.collect{case p if cond1(p) => println(Thread.currentThread); (p, true)}(breakOut)
Thread[Thread-8,5,main]
Thread[Thread-8,5,main]
Thread[Thread-8,5,main]
Thread[Thread-8,5,main]
Thread[Thread-8,5,main]
map: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Boolean] = Map(10 -> true, 8 -> true, 4 -> true, 6 -> true, 2 -> true)
```

You can see that from the thread name - the thread should contain a name `ForkJoin`-something.

### The Correct Way

The correct way to do it should be to first use the `breakOut` with the expected type being a parallel map, so that the `collect` proceeds in parallel:

```
scala> val map: parallel.mutable.ParMap[Int,Boolean] = dataList.par.collect{case p if cond1(p) => println(Thread.currentThread);(p, true)}(breakOut)
Thread[Thread-9,5,main]
Thread[Thread-9,5,main]
Thread[Thread-9,5,main]
Thread[Thread-9,5,main]
Thread[Thread-9,5,main]
map: scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParMap[Int,Boolean] = ParHashMap(10 -> true, 8 -> true, 4 -> true, 6 -> true, 2 -> true)
```

and then call `seq` on the result of `collect`, since `seq` is always `O(1)`.

**UPDATE**: just checked - this seems to work correctly with trunk, but not with 2.9.1.final.

### The Patch

But, as you can see, this doesn't work either because it is a bug, and will be fixed in the next version of Scala. A workaround:

```
scala> val map: parallel.mutable.ParMap[Int, Boolean] = dataList.par.collect{case p if cond1(p) => println(Thread.currentThread);(p, true)}.map(x => x)(breakOut)
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1,5,main]
map: scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParMap[Int,Boolean] = ParHashMap(10 -> true, 8 -> true, 4 -> true, 6 -> true, 2 -> true)

scala> val sqmap = map.seq
sqmap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Boolean] = Map(10 -> true, 8 -> true, 4 -> true, 6 -> true, 2 -> true)
```

With a note that the final `map` will currently be done sequentially.

Alternatively, if just a `parallel.ParMap` is ok with you, you can do:

```
scala> val map: Map[Int, Boolean] = dataList.par.collect{case p if cond1(p) => println(Thread.currentThread);(p, true)}.toMap.seq
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8,5,main]
map: scala.collection.Map[Int,Boolean] = Map(10 -> true, 6 -> true, 2 -> true, 8 -> true, 4 -> true)
```

Comment: You're welcome. The current design might be a bit misleading, but the general rule with transformer methods like `collect` is - if the target collection being produced is a sequential collection, the construction will proceed sequentially.