# Converting mutable collection to immutable

Tags: scala, collections

I'm looking for a best way of converting a `collection.mutable.Seq[T]` to `collection.immutable.Seq[T]`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want to convert `ListBuffer` into a `List`, use `.toList`. I mention this because that particular conversion *is performed in constant time*. Note, though, that any further use of the `ListBuffer` will result in its contents being copied first.

Otherwise, you can do `collection.immutable.Seq(xs: _*)`, assuming xs is mutable, as you are unlikely to get better performance any other way.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - I end up with an immutable sequence with one element (the mutable sequence). Silly Scala.

Answer (score 16):

As specified:

```
def convert[T](sq: collection.mutable.Seq[T]): collection.immutable.Seq[T] = 
  collection.immutable.Seq[T](sq:_*)
```

**Addition**

The native methods are a little tricky to use. They are already defined on `scala.collection.Seq` and you’ll have to take a close look whether they return a `collection.immutable` or a `collection.mutable`. For example `.toSeq` returns a `collection.Seq` which makes no guarantees about mutability. `.toIndexedSeq` however, returns a `collection.immutable.IndexedSeq` so it seems to be fine to use. I’m not sure though, if this is really the intended behaviour as there is also a `collection.mutable.IndexedSeq`.

The safest approach would be to convert it manually to the intended collection as shown above. When using a native conversion, I think it is best practice to add a type annotation including (`mutable`/`immutable`) to ensure the correct collection is returned.

Comment: Nice. But what about native methods like `.toIndexedSeq` or  `.toStream`? I'm just not sure which is a best solution.

Answer (score 6):

`toList` (or `toStream` if you want it lazy) are the preferred way if you want a `LinearSeq`, as you can be sure what you get back is immutable (because List and Stream are). There's no `toVector` method if you want an immutable `IndexedSeq`, but it seems that `toIndexedSeq` gives you a Vector (which is immutable) most if not all of the time.

Another way is to use `breakOut`. This will look at the type you're aiming for in your return type, and if possible oblige you. e.g.

```
scala> val ms = collection.mutable.Seq(1,2,3)
ms: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)

scala> val r: List[Int] = ms.map(identity)(collection.breakOut)
r: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val r: collection.immutable.Seq[Int] = ms.map(identity)(collection.breakOut)
r: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

For more info on such black magic, get some strong coffee and see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1715681/770361).

Answer (score 4):

If you are also working with `Set` and `Map` you can also try these, using `TreeSet` as an example.

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val immutableSet = TreeSet(blue, green, red, yellow)

//converting a immutable set to a mutable set
val mutableSet = mutable.Set.empty ++= immutableSet

//converting a mutable set back to immutable set
val anotherImmutableSet = Set.empty ++ mutableSet
```

The above example is from book Programming in Scala