# Will the first generator determine the result type of for comprehension?

Tags: scala

Say I have following code:

```
object ForComprehension {
  def generateSomeSeq(n: Int): List[Int] = (1 to n).toList
  def square(n: Int): List[Int] =
    for (x <- generateSomeSeq(n)) yield x * x
}
```

It all works fine. But for some reason I modify the result of first method to `Set` instead of `List`:

```
object ForComprehension {
  def generateSomeSeq(n: Int): Set[Int] = (1 to n).toSet
  def square(n: Int): List[Int] =
    for (x <- generateSomeSeq(n)) yield x * x
}
```

The scala compiler complains there's a type mismatch in first generator of for comprehension. Although it makes sense, I still expect it works in both cases. After all, there's no visual clue in for comprehension that it expects a `List` instead of a `Set`. I need to read both signatures to diagnose the type mismatch error.

Or I shouldn't expect such syntactical locality for for comprehension in the first place, should I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for comprehension in your example is really just syntactic sugar for a call to `map` and the return type of `map` is indeed determined by the type it is called on. More precisely, it is determined by the implicit `CanBuildFrom` that is available. So to make your code compile, you can convert the for comprehension to a map call and explicitly pass the usually implicit parameter:

```
object ForComprehension {
  def generateSomeSeq(n: Int): Set[Int] = (1 to n).toSet
  def square(n: Int): List[Int] = 
    generateSomeSeq(n).map(x => x * x)(scala.collection.breakOut)
}
```

About how `breakOut` works, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout).