# Copy elements from one list to another in Scala

Tags: list, scala, copy

I'm would like to create generic (invariant) method in Scala which copies elements from source list to destination list. In Java there is **copy** method in **java.util.Collections** (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29). I know in Scala List is immutable object so i would like to create and return new list.

I've written the following code:

```
def copy[T](dest:List[T], src:List[T]):List[T] = {
    if(dest.length<src.length) throw new Exception("IndexOutOfBoundsException")
    else if(src==Nil) dest
    else {
        var ret = dest
        ret = dest.updated(0, src.first)
        var i=1
        val f:(T=>Unit) = a => {
            if(i<src.length) ret=ret.updated(i, src(i))
            i+=1
            ()
        }
        dest.foreach(f)
        ret
    } 
}
```

But I think it could be written better. Could you help me to write better code? Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**: Maybe I expressed unclear what I want to do. I have two lists (scala.collection.immutable.List), e.g. **src** (length=x) and **dest**(length=y>=x). I would like to replace first **x** elements of **dest** list with elements from **src** list.

Comment: Do you mean `scala.collection.immutable.List`? It is immutable. No need to copy them.

Comment: According to your edit: you want to do it in-place? (e.g. will you be unhappy if there will be third list, say `updated` as a result of such replacement?)

Comment: It would be the best to do it in-place. I've got solution but if exists better one, i'm interested to see it.

Comment: Do not use indexed access like `src(i)` on `List`. `List` in scala is [Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). Indexed access on it is very slow.

Comment: Thank you, didn't think about it earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get an updated list you can use map on your list. Map works by applying a function to each element in the list, and returning updated list.

http://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/

Answer (score 8):

Do you mean `scala.collection.immutable.List`? It is immutable. No need to copy them. Immutable means that nothing can change it, so you can use it in different threads.

Generic way of creating collections in scala is builder. You can get one from `CanBuildFrom` object. Alternatively you can get it from `genericBuilder` method of collection instance.

```
scala> val list = List(1, 2, 3)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val b = list.genericBuilder[Int]
b: scala.collection.mutable.Builder[Int,List[Int]] = ListBuffer()

scala> list.foreach{ b += _ }

scala> val result = b.result // this code is useless. `val result = list` is enough
result: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

If you want to create new collection of different type based on existing collection, you can use [`collection.breakOut`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1716558/406435) methid like this:

```
scala> val list = List('a', 'b', 'c')
list: List[Char] = List(a, b, c)

scala> val result: String = list.map{identity}(collection.breakOut)
result: String = abc
```

**Upd**

```
require(src.length <= dest.length, "IndexOutOfBoundsException")
src ++ dest.drop(src.length)
```

Comment: For further details on BreakOut and CanBuildFrom [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1716558/298389)

Comment: Thanks, good to know that. But I would like to do something other. Maybe I explained not so good, I add something to my question.

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking far too procedurally, say what you want not how to do it...

how about:

```
val src = List(1,2,3)
val dest = src map {x => x}
```

if you really want to make a function of it

```
def copy[T](src: List[T]): List[T] = src map {x => x}
```

**in response to OP's update:**(which has also been proposed by others)

```
def copy[T](src: List[T], dest: List[T]): List[T] = src ++ dest.drop(src.length)
```

Comment: Thanks also. But I would like to do something other. Maybe I explained not so good, I add something to my question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
if(dest.length <= src.length) dest ::: src.drop(dest.length)
else dest.dropRight(dest.length - src.length) //or throw exception...
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like

```
 def copy[T](dest: Seq[T], src: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = {
   require(dest.length >= src.length)
   src ++ (dest drop src.length)
 }
```

I generalized to `Seq`s, but it works on `List`s, of course

The `require` method throws `IllegalArgumentException` if not fulfilled at runtime

Then you need only append the last (`y-x`) elements of the destination list to to the source list (where x = src.length;  y = dest.length)

You do this by *dropping* `x` elements from `dest` and *appending* the remaining to `src`.

This is what you get from the REPL

```
scala> val src = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
src: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val dst = List(10, 20)
dst: List[Int] = List(10, 20)

scala> val dst2 = List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)
dst2: List[Int] = List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)

scala> copy(dst, src)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:221)
        at .copy(<console>:8)
        at .<init>(<console>:11)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        <...>

scala> copy(dst2, src)
res1: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 50, 60)
```

Comment: Same solution proposed from @senia in her update... Her answer was bogged down in the main answer and I didn't saw that at first.