# Is there any method that does the same thing as map() but generates a different type of container?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Sometimes I need to create a collection by mapping another one with different type. For example, some function needs `List[_]` as its parameter type, but I need to produce that by mapping a `IndexedSeq[_]`:

```
val r = (1 to n).map { ... }
someFunction(r.toList)
```

Although I can fulfill that by calling `IndexedSeq[_]`'s `map` method first followed by another call to `toList`, this produces a redundant intermediate collection. Is there any way to avoid this redundant step while still keeping code concise?

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/a/1716558/298389

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the full signature for `map`:

```
def map[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

The key to this is the implicit `CanBuildFrom`, which governs how the result collection is generated from the input collection. We can replace the implicit `CanBuildFrom` with an explicit one that allows us to build a different result collection.

Even better, we don't even have to write this explicit method! It's there already, in the form of `scala.collection.breakOut`. From the ScalaDoc:

> Provides a CanBuildFrom instance that builds a specific target collection (To') irrespective of the original collection (From').

So if we pass in `collection.breakOut`, we can then specify exactly what we want to the `map` method:

```
val x = IndexedSeq(1,2,3,4,5)
x.map[Int, List[Int]](_ * 2)(collection.breakOut)
> res6: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your very clear answer. Scala's implicit parameter is so powerful and mysterious. I have just read [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits) and learnt much.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is `collection.breakOut`, as stated by om-nom-nom in his comment.

`breakOut` is an additional argument given to the `map` method, and - to keep it simple - it allows to return different types of collections from `map`:

```
def directMapExample(seq: Seq[Int]): Set[Int] = seq.map(_ * 2)(collection.breakOut)
```

Note, that the following fails at compilation:

```
def directMapExample2(seq: Seq[Int]): Set[Int] = seq.map(_ * 2)
```

For details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1716558/298389.

Comment: Thanks for your concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using a view might help?

```
val r = (1 to n).view.map { … }
someFunction(r.toList)
```

The `map` function is a strict transformer on `Range`. However, if you turn it into a view first, then that `Range` (which is a non-strict collection) will be wrapped inside an object that implements `map` in a non-strict way. The full range of values would only be produced when calling `toList`.