# Return type of Scala for/yield

Tags: scala, scala-collections, for-comprehension

I'm reading through [*Scala for the Impatient*](http://horstmann.com/scala/) and I've come across something that's got me scratching my head.

The following returns a String:

```
scala> for ( c<-"Hello"; i <- 0 to 1) yield (c+i).toChar
res68: String = HIeflmlmop
```

But this returns a Vector:

```
scala> for (i <- 0 to 1; c <- "Hello") yield (c + i).toChar
res72: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char] = Vector(H, e, l, l, o, I, f, m, m, p)
```

The text preceding these two examples reads...

> "When the body of the for loop starts with yield, then the loop
>   constructs a collection of values, one for each iteration...This type of loop is called a for comprehension. The generated collection is compatible with the first generator.

If the generated collection is compatible with the first generator, then why isn't the second example returning a type of Range, as in the following:

```
scala> val range = 0 to 1
range: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(0, 1)
```

Or am I misinterpreting entirely what the text means by, "...the generated collection is compatible with the first generator."

Comment: Take a look at [this superior answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1716558/406435) to get better view on how it works. And [here](http://www.devoxx.com/display/FR13/Martin+Odersky) (starting from 42:40) Martin Odersky himself explains history, motivation and implementation of scala collections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for-comprehensions are desugared to a series of `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` operations.

When you use `map` on a `Range`, you get a `Vector` output:

```
scala> 0 to 2 map (x => x * x)
res12: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 1, 4)
```

This is because a `Range` is a very simple sort of collection, that is essentially just <s>two</s> three numbers: a start value, an end value and a step. If you look at the result of the mapping above, you can see that the resulting values cannot be represented by something of the `Range` type.

Answer (score 0):

in this `for (i <- 0 to 1; c <- "Hello") yield (c + i).toChar` comprehension, 
the 1st generator is of Type **scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive**
the yield result vector is of Type **scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]**
and if you check the class **Range**: 
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range

it shows **Range** extends/mixin the **IndexedSeq**. the super type **IndexedSeq** is compatible with the sub type **Range**.

If the result can not be represented by a range(as the previous answer explained), it will 'search for' the super type to represent the result.

[image]