# Initializing a few variables in Scala using one method

Tags: scala

Here is a part of code I converted from Java

```
class Regex(valCollection: Collection[MyClass3]) {
  private val val1 = new HashMap[String, MyClass1]
  private val val2 = new HashMap[String, String]
  private val val3 = new HashMap[String, MyClass2]

  private val filteredValCollection = valCollection.map(x => {
    val valCollectionItem = getValCollectionItem(x)

    x.key match {
      case "123" => val1 + (valCollectionItem -> MyClass1.parse(x.value)) //TODO -- append to val1
      case "456" => val2 + (valCollectionItem -> x.value) //TODO -- append to val2
      case "789" => val3 + (valCollectionItem -> MyClass2.parse(x.value)) //TODO -- append to val3
    }

    valCollectionItem
  })

  def getValCollectionItem = { /*.....*/}
}
```

1) What I want to do is using only immutable collections and immutability initialize all 4 collections: `val1, val2, val3 and filteredValCollection`. As you can see, `filteredValCollection` was initialized and that's fine. However,

```
case "123" => val1 + (valCollectionItem -> MyClass1.parse(x.value))
```

returns a result to nowhere as well as for `val2` and `val3`.

My thought is, I have to return a `tuple` from `valCollection.map` and initialize all the collections I want afterwards.

So how do I do that?

2) Since this code came from Java code, is there any more efficient analog of `Collection[MyClass3]` in Scala world?

Comment: *is there any more efficient analog ...* efficient in what sense?

Comment: @om-nom-nom in any sense.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Java, this tag must be removed. You are attracting the eyes of Java experts, who can clearly offer no help, except if they happen to be Scala experts as well, which is what the Scala tag is for.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, just turn a blind eye to it, it should help.

Comment: No problem, I've flagged it so it's down to the site moderators. That doesn't mean I see the point of your actions, which seem to achieve nothing but the kind of conversation you are having right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With immutable collections**

```scala
def parseValCollection = {
  val elemAndItems = valCollection.map{ x => x -> getValCollectionItem(x) }
  val valCollectionItems = elemAndItems.map{ case (_, item) -> item }
  val val1Map = elemAndItems.filter{ case (x, _) => x.key == "123" }.
    map{ case (x, item) => item -> MyClass1.parse(x.value) }.toMap
  val val2Map = elemAndItems.filter{ case (x, _) => x.key == "456" }.
    map{ case (x, item) => item -> x.value }.toMap
  val val3Map = elemAndItems.filter{ case (x, _) => x.key == "789" }.
    map{ case (x, item) => item -> MyClass2.parse(x.value) }.toMap

  (valCollectionItems, val1Map, val2Map, val3Map)
}

private val (valCollectionItems, val1Map, val2Map, val3Map) = parseValCollection
```

If you want to iterate through `valCollection` only once you could use `foldLeft`, but you shouldn't do it normally - it's a classic case of the premature optimization.

If you want to reduce number of iterations you could replace `filter{...}.map{...}.toMap` with `collect{...}(breakOut)`:

```
val val1Map: Map[String, MyClass1] = elemAndItems.collect{
    case (x, item) if x.key == "123" => item -> MyClass1.parse(x.value)
  }(breakOut)
```

Alternatively you could just add `view` before `filter` to use lazy collections.

**With mutable collections**

But if you want to transform your code from java to scala you could just use mutable collections:

```
import collection.{mutable => m}

class Regex(valCollection: Iterable[MyClass3]) {
  private val val1 = m.Map[String, MyClass1]()
  private val val2 = m.Map[String, String]()
  private val val3 = m.Map[String, MyClass2]()

  private val filteredValCollection = m.Seq[ItemType]()

  for( x <- valCollection){
    val valCollectionItem = getValCollectionItem(x)
    filteredValCollection += valCollectionItem
    x.key match {
      case "123" => val1 += (valCollectionItem -> MyClass1.parse(x.value))
      case "456" => val2 += (valCollectionItem -> x.value)
      case "789" => val3 += (valCollectionItem -> MyClass2.parse(x.value))
    }
  }

  def getValCollectionItem: ItemType = { /*.....*/}
}
```

*more efficient analog of Collection[MyClass3]*

If you want to call this constructor from scala code only you should use common interface of all [scala collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html): `Traversable` or `Iterable` and leave to the caller the choice of implementation.

Comment: **With immutable collections:** - there are at least 4 loops there (maps). is there any way to do it more effectively?

Comment: @Grienders you can doesn't mean you should. You can use `foldLeft`, but with immutable collections you'll get no performance improvement, so you'll have to use builders. Solution with builders is almost the same as solution with mutable collections. You could replace `filter{...}.map{...}.toMap` with `collect{...}(brakOut)` or just add `view` before `filter` to iterate only once for each `valNMap`.

Comment: It's converted to `scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,X]` instead of `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[java.lang.String,X]`. How do I solve this?

Comment: @Grienders: I see 2 solutions. 1) just use a `Map`. Are you sure you need a `HashMap`? In scala default implementations for `Seq`, `IndexedSeq`, `Set` and `Map` are good enough. 2) replace `Map` with `HashMap` in my example with `breakOut`.

Comment: and a couple more questions: 1) roughly speaking, collect is the same as filter + map? 2) is there any way to say something like "implicit breakOut" at the beginning of `parseValCollection` to be able to omit (breakOut) in those 3 "collect" method calls? I tried but I failed.

Comment: 1) Yes, except `filter` without `view` creates new collection, so there is an intermediate collection with `filter + map`. 2) `you can doesn't mean you should`. [`breakOut`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1716558/406435) creates a `CanBuildFrom`. And `CanBuildFrom` is used not only in `collect`, but in many other collection methods. For instance in `map`. Such implicit `breakOut` will break all `map` calls.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the return type you want? `val1`, `val2`, `val3`? It's really not clear to me what you're trying to do. I'm going to assume you want to partition `valCollection` into three `HashMap`s.

Let's make a case class for that:

```
case class CollectionResult(
  val val1: HashMap[String, MyClass1],
  val val2: HashMap[String, String],
  val val3: HashMap[String, MyClass2]
)
```

If all 3 results had the same type, you could just use a simple `Tuple3`...

But let's work with `CollectionResult`. You now want a function that takes a `Collection[MyClass3]` and returns a `CollectionResult`:

```
def partition(input: Collection[MyClass3]): CollectionResult
```

As the name says, we'll go across `input`, partitioning the values as we go. Since we want one `CollectionResult`, many of them, we'll use `foldLeft`:

```
def partition(input: Collection[MyClass3]): CollectionResult = {
  val initialAccumulator = CollectionResult(HashMap.empty, HashMap.empty, HashMap.empty, Collection.empty)
  input.foldLeft(initialAccumulator)((accumulator, inputVal) => {
    val newVal1 = (if (inputVal.x == "123")  accumulator.val1 + (inputVal -> MyClass1.parse(inputVal.value)) else accumulator.val1)
    val newVal2 = (if (inputVal.x == "456") accumulator.val2 + inputVal.value else accumulator.val2)
    val newVal3 = (if (inputVal.x == "789")  accumulator.val3 + (inputVal -> MyClass2.parse(inputVal.value)) else accumulator.val3)

    CollectionResult(newVal1, newVal2, newVal3)
  })
}
```

As you can see, instances of `CollectionResult` are used to immutably pass the state through the `foldLeft()` process.

But wait, this seems like a common process. Wouldn't it be nice if Scala had a built-in method to do this? It does: `groupBy()`. It just requires a function that takes a value in and returns a key for a resulting `Map`.

Let's use it:

```
val partitioned: Map[String, Class3] = valCollection.groupBy(inputVal => inputVal.x)
val transformed: Map[String, Any] = partitioned.map((keyValue) => {
  val (key, value) = keyValue
  key match {
    case "123" => MyClass1.parse(value)
    case "789" => MyClass2.parse(value)
    case _     => value
  }
})
```

This is quite succinct, though it has the disadvantage of requiring multiple iterations (probably not a real issue) and having to use the `Any` type (a larger issue).

Comment: `I'm going to assume you want to partition valCollection into three HashMaps.` -- What I want to do is using only immutable collections and immutability initialize all 4 collections: val1, val2, val3 and filteredValCollection.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by that. But I guess the other answer addresses your goal.