# Explanation of Scala map function signature?

Tags: scala

This code applies a function to List of Ints and sets each value in the List of Option with value 4 :

```
  val l = List(1,2,3,4,5)                         //> l  : List[Int] = 
  val v = 4                                       //> v  : Int = 4
  def g(v:Int) = List(v-1, v, v+1)                //> g: (v: Int)List[Int]
 l map (x => {f(x);})                            //> res0: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(4), Some(4), Some(4), Some(4), Some(4))
```

Signature of map :

```
   def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
```

Since B is the first type parameter (in map[B, That]) does this mean its typed to the prefix operand 'l' (List) ?

How is 'A' typed ? Does the scala compiler somehow check the type within the the List 'l' and infer that its of type Int ?

How is 'That' typed ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala 2.8 breakout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout)

Comment: In your code, what is the function f? what is the use of the function g? if you look at the API doc for List, you can see that map has the following signature : def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): List[B] : it just transforms a List of A in a List of B

Comment: See **About 'CanBuildFrom`** section in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1716558/406435) by [Daniel C. Sobral](http://stackoverflow.com/users/53013/daniel-c-sobral).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simple signature for `map` in a `List[A]` is

```
def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): List[B]
```

which means that

- `A` is determined by the type parameter of the actual list

  - `Int` for the example list `l`
- `B` is determined by the target type of the function `f` passed as argument

  - `Option[Int]` for the example function `f: Int -> Option[Int]`

The expanded signature is

```
def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That
```

which exist so that you can generically map between containers that can be traversed in some way, even when the target *traversable* has a different form than the original.

> A specific example is traversing a `Map` as a container of `Pairs`,
>   with a mapping function that produces single values. The resulting
>   traversable is not a `Map` anymore, so the `CanBuildFrom` implicit
>   parameter is used to find "available representations" for the
>   resulting object.

In this signature we have

- `Repr` as the type of the original traversed container
- `B` as the target type of the contained values, as in the simplified signature
- `That` as the type of the target container, determined by the implicit existence of a `CanBuildFrom` with the correct types at call site

Comment: Could you explain why there are parenthesis around type A in the first code snippet ?

Comment: @vkubicki the parenthesis are optional, in this case. They might be needed in other situations to disambiguate, e.g. if you have a function receiving a tuple, `((A, B)) => C`