# Why Scala doesn't allow List.map _ and type signatures in REPL

Tags: scala

## Background

I recently attended a beginner Scala meetup and we were talking about the difference between methods and functions (also discussed in-depth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)).

For example:

```
scala> val one = 1
one: Int = 1

scala> val addOne = (x: Int) => x + 1
addOne: Int => Int = <function1>
```

This demonstrates that vals can not only have an integer type, but can have a function type.  We can see the type in the scala repl:

```
scala> :type addOne
Int => Int
```

We can also define methods in objects and classes:

```
scala> object Foo {
 |   def timesTwo(op: Int) = op * 2
 | }
defined module Foo
```

And while a method doesn't have a type (but rather is has a type signature), we can lift it into a function to see what it is:

```
scala> :type Foo.timesTwo
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method timesTwo in object Foo;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
          Foo.timesTwo
              ^


scala> :type Foo.timesTwo _
Int => Int
```

So far, so good.  We even talked about how functions are actually objects with an apply method and how we can de-syntactic sugarify expressions to show this:

```
scala> Foo.timesTwo _ apply(4)
res0: Int = 8

scala> addOne.apply(3)
res1: Int = 4
```

To me, this is quite helpful in learning the language because I can internalize what the syntax is actually implying.

## Problematic Example

We did, however, run into a situation that we could not identify.  Take, for example, a list of strings.  We can map functions over the values demonstrating basic Scala collections and functional programming stuff:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).map(_*4)
res2: List[Int] = List(4, 8, 12)
```

Ok, so what is the type of List(1,2,3).map()?  I would expect we would do the same :type trick in the repl:

```
scala> :type List(1,2,3).map _
<console>:8: error: Cannot construct a collection of type Nothing with elements of type Nothing based on a collection of type List[Int].
          List(1,2,3).map _
                      ^
```

From the API definition, I know the signature is:

```
def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): List[B]
```

But there is also a full signature:

```
def map[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

## Question

So there are two things I don't quite understand:

- Why doesn't the normal function lift trick work with List.map?  Is there a way to de-syntactic sugar the erroneous statement to demonstrate what is going on?
- If the reason that the method can't be lifted is due to the full signature "implicit", what exactly is going on there?

Finally, is there a robust way to inspect both types and signatures from the REPL?

Comment: Question about the implicit type signature is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18533437/125901

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you've encountered has to do with the fact that, in Scala, [functions are monomorphic, while methods can be polymorphic](http://www.chuusai.com/2012/04/27/shapeless-polymorphic-function-values-1/). As a result, the type parameters `B` and `That` must be known in order to create a function value for `List.map`.

The compiler attempts to infer the parameters but can't come up with anything sensible. If you supply parameters, you'll get a valid function type:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).map[Char, List[Char]] _
res0: (Int => Char) => List[Char] = <function1>

scala> :type res0
(Int => Char) => List[Char]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without an actual function argument, the inferred type of the function is `Int => Nothing`, but the target collection is also `Nothing`. There is no suitable `CanBuildFrom[List[Int], Nothing, Nothing]` in scope, which we can see by entering `implicitly[CanBuildFrom[List[Int], Nothing, Nothing]]` in the REPL (comes up with same error). If you supply the type parameters, then you can get a function:

```
scala> :type List(1,2,3).map[Int, List[Int]] _
(Int => Int) => List[Int]
```

I don't think you can inspect method signatures in the REPL. That's what Scaladoc is for.

Comment: I still think it would be useful to see type signatures in the REPL.  Not only would it make it easier than checking scaladoc, it would allow you to inspect code defined or composed at runtime.  Is there a way to do that without going to java.lang.reflect?

Comment: You might have more luck with `scala.reflect`, but even then it's not going to tell you what the various parameters are for or what the method does. The REPL could be improved to show the scaladoc comments, but that would still be a poor cousin of looking at scaladoc in your browser. The docs are part of the Scala distribution so just find the folder on your hard drive and have them open permanently in a browser tab.

Comment: @16bytes actually I found you can see method signatures in the REPL, using the Tab key after you've typed in the method name. It only seems to work when you have a single identifier followed by dot and method name, so if you define `val list = List(1,2,3)` then `list.map` followed by Tab displays its signature, but `List(1,2,3).map` followed by Tab gives an error message. Still, may be some use.