# Creating a Map from a Set of keys

Tags: scala, dictionary, set

I have a set of keys, say `Set[MyKey]` and for each of the keys I want to compute the value through some value function, lets say `computeValueOf(key: MyKey)`. In the end I want to have a `Map` which maps `key -> value`

What is the most efficient way to do this without iterating too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a pretty neat application for [`collection.breakOut`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.package), one of my favorite pieces of bizarre Scala voodoo:

```
type MyKey = Int

def computeValueOf(key: MyKey) = "value" * key
val mySet: Set[MyKey] = Set(1, 2, 3)

val myMap: Map[MyKey, String] =
  mySet.map(k => k -> computeValueOf(k))(collection.breakOut)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1716558/334519) for some discussion of what's going on here. Unlike the version with `toMap`, this won't construct an intermediate `Set`, saving you some allocations and a traversal. It's also much less readable, though—I only offer it because you mentioned that you wanted to avoid "iterating too much".

Comment: Does this avoids more iterations than `setOfKeys.iterator.map(key => (key, computeValueOf(key)).toMap`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still need to understand it a bit more. Yes, the reason I ask to avoid iterations as much as possible is because the problem I am working on is a bit combinatorial, so saving on iterations and `lazy val`ing where it makes sense should help.

Comment: @TravisBrown , could you please explain a bit more what the `collection.breakOut` is doing? Where is the keyword `collection` coming from? Its not declared anywhere but it works. Thanks

Comment: `collection` is just the `scala.collection` package (you can always omit the `scala.` part). Explaining `breakOut` is tricky—see Daniel Sobral's answer (linked above) for a really comprehensive attempt. In short, it says something like "find a builder that will construct the appropriate collection type and use it during the map".

Answer (score 3):

A collection of `Tuple2`s can be converted to a `Map`, where the tuple's first element will be the key and the second element will be the value.

```
val setOfKeys = Set[MyKey]()
setOfKeys.map(key => (key, computeValueOf(key)).toMap
```

Comment: Oh silly me, of course. I was going around in circles why the `toMap` function and related ones all expected the value in a tuple, which is why I asked the question. Still so green in this :(. Thanks as always!!

Comment: No problem. It takes a while until you know all the functions and what they do and after that they become a second nature. And if you switch to another language you'll **really** start to miss them :)

Comment: Yes, I have started to use Scala after years of using Java. I am enjoying it so far, but still can't find my way through the obvious (as you can see from my questions today) which tends to get frustrating sometimes.