# Yield an ArrayBuffer (or other mutable Collection type) from a for loop in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, collections, mutable

Within the confines of a single matrix related method that works with large multidimensional arrays performance and memory usage are critical.  We have a need to mutate elements of the array **in place** and thus are working with ArrayBuffer's (not Array's).

Given this use case is there a way to use for .. yield that would generate an ArrayBuffer (or at the least a mutable collection) instead of  immutable?

The following code displays the intent - though it does not compile:

```
def classify(inarr: Array[Double], arrarr: Array[Array[Double]], labels: Array[String], K: Int): String = {
 ...     
var diffmat: ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Double]] = for (row <- arrarr) yield {
  (ArrayBuffer[Double]() /: (row zip inarr)) {
    (outrow, cell) => outrow += cell._1 - cell._2
  }
}
```

The compilation error is :

```
Expression Array[ArrayBuffer[Double]] does not conform to expected type ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Double]]
```

Comment: Can you specify the types is `arrarr` and `inarr`?

Comment: @brian sure, adding to OP

Comment: By the way, `ArrayBuffer` is a lousy place to put `Double`s when you care critically about performance and memory; they're boxed.  If you can make your innermost layer `Array[Double]` you will see a dramatic increase in performance (at least 2x speed and size for heavy computation).  So do it this way to get it working, but go back and change it to a faster form once you really want to optimize.

Comment: @RexKerr  Thx for that input. The next two steps involve in -place mutation of all elements of the array[buffer]. So then .. how to tradeoff non-boxed/fast (but immutable?) Array vs slower -but mutable ArrayBuffer?

Comment: @javadba - You can do in-place mutation of elements of an `Array`.  I'm not sure what your use case is where this isn't sufficient.  (You do need an `ArrayBuffer` to conveniently add and remove elements.)

Comment: @RexKerr  OK yes agreed. Internally to that method new rows are being generated (thus the ArrayBuffer on the *outer* dimension) but the internal rows may be Arrays as you suggest.

Comment: @RexKerr  You did not leave any way to upvote your comments ;)

Comment: @javadba - Keep in mind that manual creation of arrays is also faster than generic collections operations (again due to boxing of generics).  So once you get it working, `val b = a.map(x => x*x)` should, if really performance critical, be rewritten as `val b = { val bb = new Array[Double](a.length); var i = 0; while (i < a.length) { bb(i) = a(i)*a(i); i += 1 }; bb }` or somesuch.

Comment: @RexKerr OK will watch for that. I will be measuring various alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah... a case for the "magick sprinkles" of breakOut.  Not only does it give you the collection type you want - it does it efficiently, without wasting an extra transformation.

```
object Foo {
  import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
  import scala.collection.breakOut
  val inarr: Array[Double] = Array()
  val arrarr: Array[Array[Double]] = Array()

  var diffmat: ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Double]] = (for (row <- arrarr) yield {
    (ArrayBuffer[Double]() /: (row zip inarr)) {
      (outrow, cell) => outrow += cell._1 - cell._2
    }
  })(breakOut)
}
```

The definitive writeup (IMHO) of this is [Daniel Sobral's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout).

Comment: This does not seem to change the return type from Array to ArrayBuffer.. but i will consult DS's answer in your provided link.

Comment: After viewing Daniel's answer, breakout is interesting yes - but does not appear to address the return type of Array vs ArrayBuffer. Feel free to clarify. BTW your code above did not compile for me -same error as OP.

Comment: @javadba - I re-did it on this machine and copied and pasted the whole thing into the answer (see above), to avoid any typos.  I don't know what to tell you as to why it doesn't work for you.  I'm on 2.10, but as long as you're past 2.8 I don't know that it matters.

Comment: Yes after you fixed the syntax error it does now work. This is useful.