# Another Scala CanBuildFrom issue: a collection enrichment operator that wraps another of a different type

Tags: scala, scala-collections, implicit, set-intersection, enrich-my-library

User Régis Jean-Gilles gracefully answered my previous question where I was struggling with CanBuildFrom and enrichment functions (aka "pimp my library" or "enrich my library"):

[Creating an implicit function that wraps map() in Scala with the right type: Not for the faint at heart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650456/creating-an-implicit-function-that-wraps-map-in-scala-with-the-right-type-not/20660742#20660742)

But this time I've got an even more complicated issue.

I have a function to implement variations on `intersectWith`, for intersecting collections by their keys. I've managed to make them work like proper collection functions:

```
implicit class IntersectUnionWithPimp[K, A, Repr](a: GenTraversableLike[(K, A), Repr]) {

  /**
   * Intersect two collections by their keys. This is identical to
   * `intersectWith` except that the combiner function is passed the
   * key as well as the two items to combine.
   *
   * @param b Other collection to intersect with.
   * @param combine Function to combine values from the two collections.
   */
  def intersectWithKey[B, R, That](b: GenTraversable[(K, B)])(
      combine: (K, A, B) => R)(
      implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, (K, R), That]): That = {
    ...
  }

  /**
   * Intersect two collections by their keys. Keep the ordering of
   * objects in the first collection. Use a combiner function to
   * combine items in common. If either item is a multi-map, then
   * for a key seen `n` times in the first collection and `m`
   * times in the second collection, it will occur `n * m` times
   * in the resulting collection, including all the possible
   * combinations of pairs of identical keys in the two collections.
   *
   * @param b Other collection to intersect with.
   * @param combine Function to combine values from the two collections.
   */
  def intersectWith[B, R, That](b: GenTraversable[(K, B)])(
      combine: (A, B) => R)(
      implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, (K, R), That]): That =
    a.intersectWithKey(b){ case (_, x, y) => combine(x, y) }(bf)
}
```

Now, I currently also have non-`CanBuildFrom` versions of `intersectBy` and friends, and these I can't get working as `CanBuildFrom` versions.

```
implicit class IntersectUnionByPimp[A](a: Traversable[A]) {
  /**
   * Intersect two collections by their keys, with separate key-selection
   * functions for the two collections. This is identical to
   * `intersectBy` except that each collection has its own key-selection
   * function. This allows the types of the two collections to be
   * distinct, with no common parent.
   *
   * @param b Other collection to intersect with.
   * @param key1fn Function to select the comparison key for the first
   *   collection.
   * @param key1fn Function to select the comparison key for the first
   *   collection.
   * @param combine Function to combine values from the two collections.
   */
  def intersectBy2[K, B, R](b: Traversable[B])(key1fn: A => K
      )(key2fn: B => K)(combine: (A, B) => R): Traversable[R] = {
    val keyed_a = a.map { x => (key1fn(x), x) }
    val keyed_b = b.map { x => (key2fn(x), x) }
    keyed_a.intersectWith(keyed_b)(combine).map(_._2)
  }

  /**
   * Intersect two collections by their keys. Keep the ordering of
   * objects in the first collection. Use a combiner function to
   * combine items in common. If either item is a multi-map, then
   * for a key seen `n` times in the first collection and `m`
   * times in the second collection, it will occur `n * m` times
   * in the resulting collection, including all the possible
   * combinations of pairs of identical keys in the two collections.
   *
   * @param b Other collection to intersect with.
   * @param keyfn Function to select the comparison key.
   * @param combine Function to combine values from the two collections.
   */
  def intersectBy[K, B >: A](b: Traversable[B])(keyfn: B => K)(
      combine: (A, B) => B): Traversable[B] = {
    val keyed_a = a.map { x => (keyfn(x), x) }
    val keyed_b = b.map { x => (keyfn(x), x) }
    keyed_a.intersectWith(keyed_b)(combine).map(_._2)
  }
}
```

The best version so far I can come up with is this:

```
implicit class IntersectUnionByPimp[A, Repr](a: GenTraversableLike[A, Repr]) {
  def intersectBy2[K, B, R, That](b: Traversable[B])(key1fn: A => K)(
      key2fn: B => K)(combine: (A, B) => R)(
      implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, R, That]): That = {
    // FIXME! How to make this work while calling `map`?
    // val keyed_a = a.map { x => (key1fn(x), x) }
    val keyed_a = mutable.Buffer[(K, A)]()
    a.foreach { x => keyed_a += ((key1fn(x), x)) }
    val keyed_b = b.map { x => (key2fn(x), x) }
    keyed_a.intersectWith(keyed_b)(combine).map(_._2)
  }

  def intersectBy[K, B >: A, That](b: Traversable[B])(keyfn: B => K)(
      combine: (A, B) => B)(
      implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
    // FIXME! How to make this work while calling `map`?
    // val keyed_a = a.map { x => (keyfn(x), x) }
    val keyed_a = mutable.Buffer[(K, A)]()
    a.foreach { x => keyed_a += ((keyfn(x), x)) }
    val keyed_b = b.map { x => (keyfn(x), x) }
    keyed_a.intersectWith(keyed_b)(combine).map(_._2)
}
```

First, I don't see why I need to rewrite the call to `map` that produces `keyed_a` with a mutable Buffer; seems like there must be a better way. But I still get the same sort of error on the bottom line:

```
[error] /Users/benwing/devel/textgrounder/src/main/scala/opennlp/textgrounder/util/collection.scala:1018: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[R]
[error]  required: That
[error]  Note: implicit method bufferToIndexedSeq is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
[error]       keyed_a.intersectWith(keyed_b)(combine).map(_._2)
[error]                                                  ^
```

So my questions are:

1. How to call `map` on a GenTraversableLike?
2. How to make the call to `intersectWith` work correctly? I know I have to somehow pass in a `CanBuildFrom` based on the one I received, and I know about `mapResult` on Builders, but I'm not sure what to do here, or if this is even possible.

An example of `intersectBy`, which intersects lists of floating-point numbers treating two numbers the same if their integral part is the same, and computing the absolute difference:

```
scala> List(4.5,2.3,4.2).intersectBy(List(4.6,4.8))(_.toInt){ case (a,b) => (a - b).abs }
res2: Traversable[Double] = List(0.09999999999999964, 0.2999999999999998, 0.39999999999999947, 0.5999999999999996)
```

(except that the returned type should be `List[Double]`)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: (1) You should really split this into two questions, because the second (`intersectBy2`) relies on the correct behaviour of the first (`intersectWith`). (2) It would make things easier to follow, if you gave an input and a desired output collection for `intersectWith`, e.g. if input is `List(1 -> "foo", 2 -> "bar", 2 -> "baz")`, what would be the second collection and the output.

Comment: @0__: I'm not quite sure why you want it split. `intersectWith` already works. I'm asking how to get `intersectBy` and `intersectBy2` working, and the answer to `intersectBy2` implies the answer to `intersectBy` because the former is more complex.

Comment: The implementation of `intersectWithKey` is missing, therefore this step should be first, perhaps it involves changing the precise signature.

Comment: @0__: `intersectWithKey` already works, with this precise signature. If you need to, insert a ??? as the implementation. The issue is how to get it to compile; if you insert ???, and it compiles correctly and then throws a "not-implemented" error upon running, then you've solved the problem. I'll insert the implementation if you want but it just takes up even more room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, turns out I need to create a builder to return the items, instead of trying to return them directly. The following works:

```
implicit class IntersectUnionByPimp[A, Repr](a: GenTraversableLike[A, Repr]) {
  /**
   * Intersect two collections by their keys, with separate key-selection
   * functions for the two collections. This is identical to
   * `intersectBy` except that each collection has its own key-selection
   * function. This allows the types of the two collections to be
   * distinct, with no common parent.
   *
   * @param b Other collection to intersect with.
   * @param key1fn Function to select the comparison key for the first
   *   collection.
   * @param key2fn Function to select the comparison key for the first
   *   collection.
   * @param combine Function to combine values from the two collections.
   */
  def intersectBy2[K, B, R, That](b: GenTraversable[B])(key1fn: A => K)(
      key2fn: B => K)(combine: (A, B) => R)(
      implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, R, That]): That = {
    // It appears we can't call map() on `a`.
    val keyed_a = mutable.Buffer[(K, A)]()
    a.foreach { x => keyed_a += ((key1fn(x), x)) }
    val keyed_b = b.map { x => (key2fn(x), x) }
    // Nor can we return the value of map() here. Need to use a builder
    // instead.
    val bu = bf()
    for ((_, r) <- keyed_a.intersectWith(keyed_b)(combine))
      bu += r
    bu.result
  }

  /**
   * Intersect two collections by their keys. Keep the ordering of
   * objects in the first collection. Use a combiner function to
   * combine items in common. If either item is a multi-map, then
   * for a key seen `n` times in the first collection and `m`
   * times in the second collection, it will occur `n * m` times
   * in the resulting collection, including all the possible
   * combinations of pairs of identical keys in the two collections.
   *
   * @param b Other collection to intersect with.
   * @param keyfn Function to select the comparison key.
   * @param combine Function to combine values from the two collections.
   */
  def intersectBy[K, B >: A, That](b: GenTraversable[B])(keyfn: B => K)(
      combine: (A, B) => B)(
      implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
    val keyed_a = mutable.Buffer[(K, A)]()
    a.foreach { x => keyed_a += ((keyfn(x), x)) }
    val keyed_b = b.map { x => (keyfn(x), x) }
    val bu = bf()
    for ((_, r) <- keyed_a.intersectWith(keyed_b)(combine))
      bu += r
    bu.result
  }
}
```

I'm not completely sure why just calling `map` on a `GenTraversableLike` doesn't seem to work, but so be it.