# scala.collection.breakOut vs views

Tags: scala, scala-collections

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1716558/936869) describes how `scala.collection.breakOut` can be used to prevent creating wasteful intermediate collections. For example, here we create an intermediate `Seq[(String,String)]`:

```
val m = List("A", "B", "C").map(x => x -> x).toMap
```

By using `breakOut` we can prevent the creation of this intermediate `Seq`:

```
val m: Map[String,String] = List("A", "B", "C").map(x => x -> x)(breakOut)
```

[Views solve the same problem](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html) and in addition access elements lazily:

```
val m = (List("A", "B", "C").view map (x => x -> x)).toMap
```

I am assuming the creation of the `View` wrappers is fairly cheap, so my question is: Is there any real reason to use `breakOut` over `View`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Scala 2.13, this is no longer a concern. Breakout has been removed and views are the recommended replacement.

---

[Scala 2.13 Collections Rework](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2017/02/28/collections-rework.html)

*Views are also the recommended replacement for collection.breakOut.
 For example,*

```
val s: Seq[Int] = ... 
val set: Set[String] = s.map(_.toString)(collection.breakOut)
```

*can be expressed with the same performance characteristics as:*

```
val s: Seq[Int] = ... 
val set = s.view.map(_.toString).to(Set)
```

Answer (score 13):

You're going to make a trip from England to France.

With view: you're taking a set of notes in your notebook and boom, once you've called .force() you start making all of them: `buy a ticket, board on the plane, ....`

With breakOut: you're departing and boom, you in the Paris looking at the Eiffel tower. You don't remember how exactly you've arrived there, but you did this trip actually, just didn't make any memories.

Bad analogy, but I hope this give you a taste of what is the difference between them.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think `views` and `breakOut` are identical.

A `breakOut` is a `CanBuildFrom` implementation used to simplify transformation operations by eliminating intermediary steps. E.g get from A to B without the intermediary collection. A `breakOut` means letting Scala choose the appropriate builder object for maximum efficiency of producing new items in a given scenario. More details [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout).

`views` deal with a different type of efficiency, the main sale pitch being: "No more new objects". Views store light references to objects to tackle different usage scenarios: lazy access etc.

Bottom line:

If you `map` on a `view` you may still get an intermediary collection of references created before the expected result can be produced. You could still have superior performance from:

```
collection.view.map(somefn)(breakOut)
```

Than from:

```
collection.view.map(someFn)
```

Answer (score 1):

What flavian said.

One use case for views is to conserve memory.  For example, if you had a million-character-long string `original`, and needed to use, one by one, all of the million suffixes of that string, you might use a collection of

```
val v = original.view
val suffixes = v.tails
```

views on the original string.  Then you might loop over the suffixes one by one, using `suffix.force()` to convert them back to strings within the loop, thus only holding one in memory at a time.  Of course, you could do the same thing by iterating with your own loop over the indices of the original string, rather than creating any kind of collection of the suffixes.

Another use-case is when creation of the derived objects is expensive, you need them in a collection (say, as values in a map), but you only will access a few, and you don't know which ones.

If you really have a case where picking between them makes sense, prefer *breakOut* unless there's a good argument for using *view* (like those above).

- *Views* require more code changes and care than *breakOut*, in that you need to add *force()* where needed.  Depending on context, failure to do so is
  often only detected at run-time.  With *breakOut*, generally if it
  compiles, it's right.
- In cases where view does not apply, *breakOut*
  will be faster, since view generation and forcing is skipped.
- If you use a debugger, you can inspect the collection contents, which you
  can't meaningfully do with a collection of views.