# Create a map from a collection using a function

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I want to create a map from a collection by providing it a mapping function. It's basically equivalent to what a normal `map` method does, only I want it to return a `Map`, not a flat collection.

I would expect it to have a signature like

```
def toMap[T, S](T => S): Map[T, S]
```

when invoked like this

```
val collection = List(1, 2, 3)
val map: Map[Int, String] = collection.toMap(_.toString + " seconds")
```

the expected value of `map` would be

```
Map(1 -> "1 seconds", 2 -> "2 seconds", 3 -> "3 seconds")
```

The method would be equivalent to

```
val collection = List(1, 2, 3)
val map: Map[Int, String] = collection.map(x => (x, x.toString + " seconds")).toMap
```

is there such a method in Scala?

Comment: you might be talking about `zipWithIndex`

Answer (score 3):

There is no such single method.  As you say, you can use `map` followed by `toMap`.  If you are concerned about the intermediary list you are creating, you might consider using `breakOut` as the implicit second argument to `map`:

```
import scala.collection.breakOut
val map: Map[Int, String] = collection.map(x => (x._1, x._2.toString + " seconds"))(breakOut)
```

You can read more about `breakOut` and the implicit argument of `map` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout).

This method allows you to construct other types that have a suitable `CanBuildFrom` implementation as well, without the intermediate step:

```
val arr: Array[(Int, String)] = collection.map(x => (x._1, x._2.toString + " seconds"))(breakOut)
```

You might also want to consider using views which inhibit creating of intermediary collections:

```
val m = (List("A", "B", "C").view map (x => x -> x)).toMap
```

The differences between these approaches are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285620/scala-collection-breakout-vs-views).

Finally, there is the `mapValues` method, which might be suitable for your purposes, if you are only mapping the values of each key-value pair.  Be careful, though, since this method actually returns a view, and might lead to unexpected performance hits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wasn't specifically worried about the intermediary collection. It just felt like something that may have been a part of the standard library, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I agree that it is missing.  In .NET, the `ToMap` method takes arguments that allow you to define the key and value using lambdas, which is often useful.  `mapValues` is a nice helper, though.

Answer (score 3):

scalaz has a `fproduct` method for `Functors` which returns things in the right shape for calling .toMap on the result:

```
scala> import scalaz._,Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> val collection = List(1, 2, 3)
collection: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> collection.fproduct(_.toString + " seconds").toMap
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> 1 seconds, 2 -> 2 seconds, 3 -> 3 seconds)
```