# How to return multiple items from a list, given their indices?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Let's say, I have a list. If I want to return something at the index of that list, I can just pass the lists' val, the index. Like so.

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3) 
list(0) //Int = 1
```

But what if I want items at multiple indexes on this list? I want to be able to do this... `list(0, 1)` and get a collection of the items at those indices.

This is crazily simple in Ruby. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 13):

You can flip the logic around, so that for each index, you're getting the index, you retrieve the element at that index.  Since you are using the `apply` method on `List`, there are several shorthand expressions of this logic:

```
val indices = List(0, 1)
indices.map(index => list.apply(index))
indices.map(index => list(index))
indices.map(list(_))
indices.map(list)
indices map list
```

It's worth noting that since these are all `maps` on `indices`, the resulting collection will generally have the same type as `indices`, and not `list`:

```
val list = Array(1, 2, 3)
val indices = List(0, 1)
indices map list //List(1, 2), instead of Array(1, 2)
```

This can be an undesirable property here.  One solution to this is to use `breakOut` (in `scala.collection`):

```
val newList: Array[Int] = indices.map(list)(breakOut)
```

You can read more about breakOut [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout).  The following solutions also maintain the collection type of `list` when possible by performing operations on `list` instead of `indeces`:

If you are looking for a contiguous range of the list, you might consider using `slice`:

```
list.slice(1, 2) //List(2)
```

You could also use `drop` and `take` (and the `dropRight`, `takeRight` versions) to a similar effect:

```
list.drop(1).take(1)
```

For more complex versions of this type of filtering, you might be interested in the `zipWithIndex` method, which would allow you to express arbitrary logic on the index:

```
list.zipWithIndex.collect { 
    case(el, index) if indices.contains(index) /* any other logic */ => el 
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted a simple and elegant solution, one comparable with Ruby.

Comment: For me its elegant. +1

Comment: I guess beauty is in the eye of the beholder; to me it's ugly.

Comment: `indeces.map(index => list(index))` is not ugly IMO, and the intent is clear. I can agree with you that `indeces.map(list)` is a bit obfuscated however.

Comment: You don/'t even need the brackets or the dot. `indeces map list` `will do it.

Comment: `indeces.map(list)` may look obfuscated because of the generic variable names. Once you're used to functional programming, `positions.map(itemByPosition)` is as readable as it gets.

Answer (score 5):

The answer from @Ben is spot on.

However, if you want to be able to use the syntax you describe `list(0, 1)`, then Scala allows you to do that through implicit conversions:

```
implicit class MultiIndexList[A](list: List[A]){
    def apply(indices: Int *) = indices.map(list)
}
```

Assuming you are working on the REPL:

```
val list = List(1,2,3)

list(1,2)
res1: Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(2, 3)

list(0,2)
res2: Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 3)
```

Comment: This is an important technique to master and definitely a great option in similar situations, but for such a simple and common problem, I would encourage OP to use the accepted idioms of the language

Comment: I agree. This is a bit on the advanced side. I was just trying to show that Scala can be cooler than Ruby :).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an equivalent to Ruby's [`Array#slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-slice) (aka [`Array#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D)) method, there are two:

- the equivalent to Ruby's `Array#[](index)` is, as you mentioned, [`List.apply(n: Int): A`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@apply(n:Int):A)
- the equivalent to Ruby's `Array#[](range)` is [`List.slice(from: Int, until: Int): List[A]`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@slice(from:Int,until:Int):List[A])
- there is no equivalent to Ruby's `Array#[](start, length)`

There is also no equivalent to Ruby's [`Array#values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-values_at).

Comment: Guessing at what `Array#[](start, length)` does `seq.drop(start).take(length)` will probably do it.