# Return a specified list range in Scala

Tags: list, scala, printing

Say we have a simpleList and want to print a specified list range. How is this done in Scala?

```
val simpleList= List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
println(simpleList(0))  //> Value 1
println(simpleList(0:4)) //> No output
```

Comment: Why has the 3rd line no output?

Comment: Because the list range needs to be given with a .slice() method -- see below. I just typed in "No output".

Answer (score 0):

Found an indication [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878607/how-to-return-multiple-items-from-a-list-given-their-indices):

```
println(numberList.slice(0,4))  //> List(1, 2)
```