# What's up with immutable.Map.map?

Tags: scala

How does [immutable.Map.map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map@map[B](f:A=>B):scala.collection.immutable.Map[B]) work? It looks like there is something wrong with the documentation:

> ```
> def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): Map[B]
> ```
>
> [use case]
>   Builds a new collection by applying a function to all elements of this immutable map.
>
> Full Signature
>
> ```
> def map[B, That](f: ((A, B)) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Map[A, B], B, That]): That
> ```

- `Map[B]` does not make sense since `Map` takes two type parameters.
- In the full signature, there is a name conflict between `B` the type argument of `map`, and `B` the type parameter of `Map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The understandable confusion stems from the fact that `map` is not implemented in `Map`, but in `TraversableLike`. However, the function documentation in inherited by sub classes.

`TraversableLike` takes two type parameters `TraversableLike[+A, +Repr]` and the map function has the signature `TraversableLike.map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): Traversable[B]`. In the api docs of `Map` the documentation for that is inherited and partly adjusted `Traversable[B]` by `Map[B]`, but `B` from `TraversableLike` is not resolved to `(A, B)` form `Map`.

(Might be a bug in Scaladoc, that probably won't be fixed, as there could be an erasure problem. But that's just guessing on my side.)

You can check what is actually implemented in `Map` if you configure visibility of members right above the members documentation.

**EDIT:**

Now to your core question:

If the documentation would give us, what we could read intuitively

and if we simplify it a bit for readability

and if we than further use a bit more of natural language instead of acronyms, the signature of map for a `Map[A, B]` could look like:

```
map[ResultItem, ResultCollection](f: (A,B) => ResultItem)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Map[A, B], ResultItem, ResultCollection]): ResultCollection
```

So, basically you apply a function to each key-value-pair of the `Map` that transforms a key-value-pair of type (A,B) into a value of type `ResultType`.

As you can build almost any kind of collection from a map (or any other collection), this result type does not have to be another tuple. And `ResultCollection` does not have to be another `Map`. E.g.:

```
Map("1" -> 1, "2" -> 2).map((keyValuePair: (String, Int)) => keyValuePair._2)
```

or short

```
Map("1" -> 1, "2" -> 2).map(_._2)
```

has `List(1, 2)` as result, `List[Int]` as ResultCollection, `Int` as ResultItem.

This is possible because of the implicit `CanBuildFrom` parameter that adds an implicit builder that takes the result of the map function and appends it to its builder-result. In most cases `CanBuildFrom` is inferred by the compiler. However, there are cases when it will not be able to infer the proper result collection.

In such cases you have to give the compiler more information:

```
val test2: Vector[Int] = Map("1" -> 1, "2" -> 2).map(_._2)(collection.breakOut)
val test3: Set[Int] = Map("1" -> 1, "2" -> 2).map(_._2)(collection.breakOut)
```

For more information on `breakOut` and `CanBuildFrom` I'd recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout/1716558#1716558)

Comment: I understand that the doc is messed up, but you did not answer the core of my question: "How does immutable.Map.map work?"