# Create an instance of a generic type in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, scala-collections

I am trying my hand at a bit of generic programming with Scala and am trying to figure out how to create an instance of a class of type `CC` as described in the code below.  I have defined the following abstract trait...

```
/** Trait defining the interface for an `OrderBook`.
  *
  * @tparam O type of `Order` stored in the order book.
  * @tparam CC type of collection used to store `Order` instances.
  */
trait OrderBook[O <: Order, CC <: collection.GenMap[UUID, O]] {

  /** All `Orders` contained in an `OrderBook` should be for the same `Tradable`. */
  def tradable: Tradable

  /** Add an `Order` to the `OrderBook`.
    *
    * @param order the `Order` that should be added to the `OrderBook`.
    */
  def add(order: O): Unit

  /** Filter the `OrderBook` and return those `Order` instances satisfying the given predicate.
    *
    * @param p predicate defining desirable `Order` characteristics.
    * @return collection of `Order` instances satisfying the given predicate.
    */
  def filter(p: (O) => Boolean): Option[collection.GenIterable[O]] = {
    val filteredOrders = existingOrders.filter { case (_, order) => p(order) }
    if (filteredOrders.nonEmpty) Some(filteredOrders.values) else None
  }

  /** Find the first `Order` in the `OrderBook` that satisfies the given predicate.
    *
    * @param p predicate defining desirable `Order` characteristics.
    * @return `None` if no `Order` in the `OrderBook` satisfies the predicate; `Some(order)` otherwise.
    */
  def find(p: (O) => Boolean): Option[O] = existingOrders.find { case (_, order) => p(order) } match {
    case Some((_, order)) => Some(order)
    case None => None
  }

  /** Return the head `Order` of the `OrderBook`.
    *
    * @return `None` if the `OrderBook` is empty; `Some(order)` otherwise.
    */
  def headOption: Option[O] = existingOrders.values.headOption

  /** Remove and return the head `Order` of the `OrderBook`.
    *
    * @return `None` if the `OrderBook` is empty; `Some(order)` otherwise.
    */
  def remove(): Option[O] = {
    headOption match {
      case Some(order) => remove(order.uuid)
      case None => None
    }
  }

  /** Remove and return an existing `Order` from the `OrderBook`.
    *
    * @param uuid the `UUID` for the order that should be removed from the `OrderBook`.
    * @return `None` if the `uuid` is not found in the `OrderBook`; `Some(order)` otherwise.
    */
  def remove(uuid: UUID): Option[O]

  /* Underlying collection of `Order` instances. */
  protected def existingOrders: CC

}
```

...and then hidden implementations of this trait in the companion object in order to force users who wish to create their own special `OrderBook` classes to use the interface defined in the trait rather than subclass from concrete implementations.  Here is the companion object...

```
object OrderBook {

  import scala.collection.mutable
  import scala.collection.parallel

  def apply[O <: Order, CC <: mutable.Map[UUID, O]](tradable: Tradable): OrderBook[O, CC] = {
    new MutableOrderBook[O, CC](tradable)
  }

  def apply[O <: Order, CC <: parallel.mutable.ParMap[UUID, O]](tradable: Tradable): OrderBook[O, CC] = {
    new ParallelMutableOrderBook[O, CC](tradable)
  }

  private class MutableOrderBook[O <: Order, CC <: mutable.Map[UUID, O]](val tradable: Tradable)
    extends OrderBook[O, CC] {

    /** Add an `Order` to the `OrderBook`.
      *
      * @param order the `Order` that should be added to the `OrderBook`.
      */
    def add(order: O): Unit = {
      require(order.tradable == tradable)  // can be disabled by compiler?
      existingOrders(order.uuid) = order
    }

    /** Remove and return an existing `Order` from the `OrderBook`.
      *
      * @param uuid the `UUID` for the order that should be removed from the `OrderBook`.
      * @return `None` if the `uuid` is not found in the `OrderBook`; `Some(order)` otherwise.
      */
    def remove(uuid: UUID): Option[O] = existingOrders.remove(uuid)

    /* Underlying collection of `Order` instances. */
    protected val existingOrders: CC = ??? // I want this to be an empty instance of type CC!

  }

  private class ParallelMutableOrderBook[O <: Order, CC <: parallel.mutable.ParMap[UUID, O]](val tradable: Tradable)
    extends OrderBook[O, CC] {
      /// details omitted for brevity!
  }

}
```

I would like to figure out how to create an empty instance of type `CC` in my implementation of `MutableOrderBook`.  I tam hopeful that this can be done without reflection.  If reflection is required, I would be open to suggestions on how to avoid using reflection for this use case. Thoughts?

Comment: any reason why you have the type `CC <: collection.GenMap[UUID, O]]` in the trait and `CC <: mutable.Map[UUID, O]` in the object?

Comment: @samer I want to over-load the apply method so that the companion object becomes a factory. The type bounds are what I plan to overload. I have updated the object to demonstrate this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[-From, -Elem, +To]`, which is made exactly for this problem.

```
private class MutableOrderBook[O <: Order, CC <: mutable.Map[UUID, O]]
    (val tradable: Tradable)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, Nothing, CC]) {
    //give me a CanBuildFrom, which can build a CC  out of Nothing.

    ...

    val existingOrders: CC = cbf().result
}
```

The scala collections library use CanBuildFrom a lot internally, for example to build the right collection in `map` and `flatMap`. For further information read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1716558/5530681) answer.

Comment: I am trying to implement your solution. But can not seem to get the code to compile.  If I understand correctly the `Elem` type in this case should be `(UUID, O)`. But what to use for the `From` type? Do I need to create my own bespoke `CanBuildFrom` or should I be able to use one that is already implicitly defined in scope? I would think that there should already be an implicit in scope for building a sub-type of `mutable.Map[UUID, O]` out of any collection of elements `(UUID, O).

Comment: We don't care about `To` and `From`, so I used Nothing. Due to contravariance, any CanBuildFrom with CC as `To` is a subtype of CanBuildFrom[Nothing, Nothing, CC] and will suit our needs. In other words, we don't care what kind of elements it can build, because we actually don't need to add anything to the builder. What error do you get?

Comment: I get and error saying that the compiler doesn't know how to build a collection of type `CC` with elements of `Nothing` out of `Nothing`.

Comment: It should work if do it like [this](http://www.scala-repl.org/code/60e8d0b1-8aab-414b-a64e-2dacf4430fb4), which is basically adding a `CanBuildFrom[_, _, CC]` parameter to apply, and specifying the type arguments explicitly when invoking apply.