# How to choose the output collection type in Seq.map?

Tags: scala, generics, collections

I'd like to implement something like:

```
def f(s: Seq[Int]): Vector[String] = s.map(_.toString).toVector
```

But I'd like it to create directly the output Vector without executing the `map` first, making whatever Seq, before copying it into a Vector.

`Seq.map` takes an implicit `canBuilFrom` parameters which induces the collection output type. So I tried `s.map(...)(Vector.canBuildFrom[String])` which gives the error:

```
 found   : scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Vector.Coll,String,scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String]]
(which expands to)  scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[_],String,scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String]]
 required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Seq[Int],String,Vector[String]]
       def f(s: Seq[Int]): Vector[String] = s.map(_.toString)(Vector.canBuildFrom[String])
```

Basically it doesn't infer correctly the first type argument of the CanBuildFrom

How can that be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`breakOut`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/#breakOut[From,T,To](implicitb:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,T,To]):scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[From,T,To]) is what you're looking for

```
def f(s: Seq[Int]): Vector[String] = s.map(_.toString)(collection.breakOut)
```

For an in-depth discussion of what `breakOut` does, check out this StackOverflow question: [Scala 2.8 breakOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout)

Comment: I would up-vote it twice if I could.
It's so simple to use that I now have `collection.breakout` all over my code :-)

Comment: @Juh_ you're welcome! Then why did you remove the accepted mark from the answer? Trying to upvote it twice? :)

Comment: Sorry. I did not realised that I removed it.